# Is it possible REMOVE ADOBE LOGO from its related tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags, advertising, usability

Hi,

Now on SO, whether it allows Microsoft, Adobe, Oracle and other companies logos to its related tags, will become something like a big carnival - Imagine many company tags in different colors. If possible, remove them from SO. If do not, put it in black and white instead color. SO is better in a clean and efficient design.

Think about it.

Comment: remove bug tag, please

Comment: Do you have a mock do of the tag logos in black and white? (Fink about it? Are you Ali G?)

Comment: Any good logo works fine in collor and black and white.

Comment: You can create a simple Mock in black and white in Photoshop. There is black and white option.

Answer (score 5):

Since it is part of an advertising campaign ("sponsored tags"), most likely you'll see more of this.  The reaction has been more positive than negative from what I can tell, so I'm guessing you should prepare yourself for more...

See a pretty big post on this topic here.
[Adobe-sponsored tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23955/adobe-sponsored-tags)

Comment: Maybe in Black and White instead collor would be better.

Comment: Yes, should be BW and not colored. (Like the icons in the mac menubar, looks classy compared to windows!)

Answer (score 3):

If you really don't like them, here you'll find how to get rid of them:

> [User script to remove SO sponsored tag advertisements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24065/user-script-to-remove-so-sponsored-tag-advertisements)

there is also an answer to that question that provides an [alternative image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24065/user-script-to-remove-so-sponsored-tag-advertisements/24073#24073). So you could create the B/W one yourself and replace it with that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great experiment that has the potential to vastly increase the profitability of SO and the other *n* sites in the trilogy. The said logos are simple png images which should be easy to block if you are really that bothered by them.

I would recommend the logos in tags to be not B&W but grayscale.

I believe (and hope), as this experiment evolves, the SO team will address the issue of search results lighting up like a Christmas tree with logos by limiting the places where a logo will be shown and the number of different logos on a page.

If they are lucky enough to, say, have Microsoft sponsors the `internet-explorer` tag and Sun sponsor the `javascript` tag, they will have to figure out a way to decide what to do for questions with both tags anyway.