# Add icon to Java tag

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, icons

Considering there are icons for the [performance](/questions/tagged/performance) tag, the [flex](/questions/tagged/flex) tag, the [android](/questions/tagged/android) tag, and some other ones, won't it be possible to have an icon for the [java](/questions/tagged/java) tag too?

Comment: Only if you're prepared to stump up for some sponsorship. See - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23959/whats-this-about-labelled-tags and others for more information

Comment: shame the stackexchange cant allow users to do this to improve the user experience.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Those are called "sponsored tags", the only way to get an icon on them is to [sponsor them](http://inedomedia.com/stackoverflow.aspx).

No idea [how much that will set you back though](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30988/how-much-does-it-cost-to-sponsor-a-tag)...

There's also this [Open Source Advertising - Sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31913/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2010) thing, although I'm not sure if java fits in there. Didn't it become open source recently? These are the requirements:

> It must be an advertisement **soliciting
>   the participation and contribution of
>   programmers writing actual source
>   code**. This is not intended as a
>   general purpose ad for consumer
>   products which just happen to be open
>   source. It's for finding programmers
>   who will help contribute code or other
>   programmery things (documentation,
>   code review, bugfixes, etc).

**Edit**: I just now realize that this sidebar thing has nothing to do with tags, only an ad in the sidebar. I leave it in here just in case...

Answer (score 17):

You can also use Greasemonkey to [remove sponsored tags completely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24065/user-script-to-remove-so-sponsored-tag-advertisements), or [add icons to common tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24480/script-to-add-more-branded-icons-to-so-tags-to-offset-adobe-branding/24481#24481).

That looks like

[image]

Comment: Well, using Opera, greasemonkey scripts are not really usable ...

Comment: @Riduidel: are you saying that *this script* doesn't work or that you didn't know that you can have User Scripts in Opera?

Comment: I've loaded it in Opera (since user.js can handle greasemonkey scripts, which I forgot). But it required some hackin' to work correctly (and even now, I keep having issues regarding operating-system having the opera tag, and android having the .net one (which I find really weird)).
Anyway, now it is hacked to work correctly, my stackoverflow is full of favicon ! cheers !
ow, the modified script can be seen at (I plan to remove regular expressions soon) : http://gist.github.com/333043

Comment: @Rid: change `[ /opera/, "http://www.opera.com/favicon.ico"]` for `[ /opera$/, "http://www.opera.com/favicon.ico"]`

Comment: Perl needs a camel! :)

Comment: @Ether: I thought that Schneier's face in the security tag was enough ;)

Comment: @voyager well, i'm OK for opera, and i'm even ok for your whole script, don't get me wrong, but I wander if we could not find a more elegant way to grab those icons urls ...