# Add an image to a tag

Tags: support, tags, images, icons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do icons on the tags mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean)

I would like to add a little image to a tag. What it the needed reputation for that? How could I do that?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're referring to sponsored tags. Those cost money.

Comment: What? And what about open source libraries or languages?

Comment: Tags with icons are [sponsored tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean). [They cost money to sponsor, not reputation on the site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42287/add-icon-to-java-tag). You can figure out more info on how you can sponsor these tags by checking out the [advertising info](http://engine.adzerk.net/redirect/0/2776/2751/0/4de3c60f719c4dfcb1a57531c7050090/0) link in the footer.

Comment: Hm. I'm not sure the Java question is a dupe; this one seems like the better dupe, as it's more generic.

Comment: @Pop In this scenario, I don't consider there to be enough distinction between "Can I add an image to a tag" and "Can I add an image to a specific tag" that the direction of closure is truly important. We can always edit the Java one to say "Add icon to tag, like Java", with it being that Java is more of an example than the necessary point. That saves us the trouble of needing to merge in order to keep the answer on the open question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See comments. In brief, tags with icons are [sponsored tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean).