# Allow icons on tags not only for sponsors

Tags: feature-request, tags, sponsored-tags

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What do icons on the tags mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean)
>   [Add icon to Java tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42287/add-icon-to-java-tag)

Having images on tags is currently reserved for sponsors – can this please be changed, so we can have more tags with icons? It makes the sites much prettier.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, this is a feature request asking for the ability to edit the icons into the tag.

Comment: @Lance: Then it needs to be stated differently. At the moment icon-tags are reserved for sponsoring...the request should reflect that then.

Comment: Thanks, just changed it a little to reflect that.

Comment: Drop mad cash on Jeff and you can put a pic of whatever you want on wherever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a bad idea because:

- StackOverflow is getting money from it
- There would be icons everywhere
- It loses sense to be a sponsor

Comment: uhmm... *loses :)