# What is "rg" and why is it sponsoring the "performance" tag?

Tags: discussion, advertising, sponsored-tags

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What does rg mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-does-rg-mean)
>   [Should tags that represent concepts be sponsorable?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33081/should-tags-that-represent-concepts-be-sponsorable)

I saw a tag with an "rg" icon - I had no idea what "rg" referred to, so I clicked to the tag's page - all the sponsored-links were obscured with the `ads.stackoverflow.com` redirect, thus were no immediate help..

Could a short paragraph of text be added to all the sponsored tag pages, explaining what is is? Even a single sentence along the lines of "This tag brought to you buy.. Redgate! **thumbs up**" would be perfect. There's no point in trying to increase their brand-awareness when I have no idea what the brand actually is..

This is not a hugely important thing - the `rg` icon filename was `tag-redgate.png`, and the links went to redgate's site - but having this information more immediately obvious would be nice.

As far as advertising goes, the sponsored tags are one of my favourite examples of unobtrusive web advertising.. but, a company selling SQL/.NET/Exchange utilities sponsoring generic tags like "performance" just doesn't seem "right". The sponsorship seems utterly irrelevant to a question tagged `[c++] [performance]` or similar..

Adobe sponsoring the `flash` tag is a great idea. Redgate sponsoring `sql-server` too.. but, are there limits to what a company can sponsor? Could EvilCorp (who write iTunes based nuclear-warhead design tools, in BASIC) sponsor the `c#`, `java`, `php`, `c++` and `jquery` tags, purely because they are the most popular, and will be used on a wide range of questions?

I'm sure "Here, let us give you money!" far outweighs "$COMPANY sponsoring $TAG doesn't seem.. right" - so I'm mainly interested in other people's opinion, and if the SO team have any (unwritten?) guidelines on who can sponsor which tags..

Comment: Just noticed http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33081/should-tags-that-represent-concepts-be-sponsorable which is basically the same as the second half of my question. The second part is different, however

Comment: Duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-does-rg-mean/