# Suggestion: Do not allow Sponsorship of general tags or tags related to products not owned

Tags: feature-request, tags, advertising, sponsored-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should tags that represent concepts be sponsorable?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33081/should-tags-that-represent-concepts-be-sponsorable)

The one that most irks me is Red Gate sponsoring performance.  It is clearly a general tag, intended to be used for any question related to improving performance.  Most of these questions have *nothing at all* to do with Red Gate related tools or products.  Red Gate does not own performance.  I'm sure they would love to have their name associated with it in the minds of developers, but so would every other software company on the face of the Earth.  Every time I see the performance tag with the little "rg" in front of it I think of "Red Gate Performance".  It makes me think the question has something to do with a Red Gate product.  It's very misleading, and I believe it is inappropriate.

It's one thing when a company is paying sponsor a tag about a product they own - such as Microsoft sponsoring the various .NET tags or the SQL-Server tag, or Oracle sponsoring the Oracle tag, or even Java sponsoring the java tag, etc.  It's a whole different deal for a company to sponsor a general tag like performance, optimization or object-oriented design patterns.  And it'd be even worse if SO were to allow companies to sponsor tags for products they don't own.  Can you imagine the cognitive dissonance that would result from Apple sponsoring, and having it's little Apple logo on, the Windows tag?

So, my proposal, only allow companies to sponsor tags for products they created and or own.  Do not allow companies to sponsor general tags, such as performance.  What say you?

Comment: Ahh, looked for that, but it didn't come up in my search for some reason.

Comment: I changed the tag from discussion to feature-request.  Clearly this has already been discussed a couple of times.  I'd like to formally request this as a "feature", because - honestly - this bothers the hell out of me.

Comment: Voting to delete - I'll move my question to an answer on the previous thread (with some rewording).