# I think it's inappropriate to have a .NET company "occupy" generic tags like "testing" and "unit-testing"

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm a bit frustrated by the fact that `[testing]` and `[unit-testing]` are now branded with Telerik's logo. Not because I have something against Telerik (it is a company from my country and I know people there), but because these tags are generic - they are used by Java, Ruby, Python, etc., etc. questions, so it is irrelevant to show Telerik in a `[java]` + `[unit-testing]` question.

It won't be just a rant:

- I'd like to see opinions whether or not this is a good idea
- Can a "conditional branded tag" be implemented? For example, brand it only in combination with certain other tags. This would make the tag page (with the promoted links) require two entry modes - one from a branded tag, and one from a regular one. But this can be done by a simple GET parameter.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33081/should-tags-that-represent-concepts-be-sponsorable