# Testing == telerik?

Tags: discussion, sponsored-tags

I am seeing "Telerik" for testing. This is right. You should not doing for money.

Does it mean that testing = Telerik?

If you are getting money then You cant do like this ..

These are my thoughts:

General computer concepts. This icon is right one...

For example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unit-testing

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33081/should-tags-that-represent-concepts-be-sponsorable and more directly http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51068/i-think-its-inappropriate-to-have-a-net-company-occupy-generic-tags-like-tes

Comment: So You people are planning to close this question with out answering

Comment: @joe see the duplicate questions for answers on the issue. While I'm against this particular tag sponsoring, too, I don't see anything wrong in the basic idea of sponsoring tags. Way, way better than having four skyscraper-sized ads on every page.

Comment: @joe - This question has been answered generically in the above two linked questions.  It's a duplicate FAQ.  Do the existing questions NOT answer this question?  If they do not, please re-phrase your question to make it clear that the answers in the above questions do not apply.

Comment: If you're so upset at this, have you considered the fact that there are other venues which use different profit models which may be more suited to you?

Comment: so you are saying me to Get Out .if i am asking question !.. Good Logic Dear...

Comment: Also bear in mind that SO et al. are free services (at least I didn't pay anything). The bandwidth alone will cost a lot of money. I think we just have to live with advertising on the net (and not only on the net).

Comment: @Marcel: Not that I agree with the OP, but "have to live with it" is not true as well. It also works *without* advertising: look at Wikipedia!

Comment: @fretje: You're right, but the Wikimedia Foundation relies (almost) solely on [donations](http://wikimediafoundation.org/wiki/FAQ/en#How_is_the_Wikimedia_Foundation_funded.3F). Though I can imagine some organizations donate servers and bandwidth to SO (et al.), I don't think these sites can be run on donations alone. Don't understand me wrong, I don't ‘like’ advertisements as well, but those on SO are not that distracting as those banners I saw in the 90's.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called advertising, and it's a fact of life.

I used to really hate it, too, and then Stack Overflow came along and in a very direct way demonstrated what an ad supported model might look like vs. the alternative ([Experts-Exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experts-Exchange)). I realized that putting up with a little mostly-unobtrusive advertising is by far the better option.

Comment: Its called Overriding and Killing old standards with your power .

Comment: Tell me one good reason .. why you people wont remove that sponsership ..

Comment: How much money they are paing for it .. !

Comment: @joe SO doesn't remove the sponsorship because the people who work here need to get paid, and this is SO's profit model.

Comment: actually i am passion about testing . When i seen this i got hurt .. thats y i shouting .. Its ok .. if some thing is living with that .. then its ok to kill standards and change anything ..

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you're that passionate about it, you can purchase the tag yourself! Just comment on this answer and I'll get a quote from the gentlemen at Inedo Media and have you going for say, 6 months?

Comment: your are good business man ..

Answer (score 0):

> You should not doing for money.

Why not?  There is nothing unethical or illegal about this and you fail to explain why this should be changed.  Please, try to explain you reasoning further so we may approach your question better.

Comment: Testing Standard. Its not belong to anyone .. But this is showing like telerik  standard ( hidden way )

Comment: @joe - This is not much different than buying keywords on google, and getting keyword based advertising to show up next to search results.  Do you disagree with all forms of advertising that are based on generic words?