# Telerik sponsored tags are just wrong

Tags: discussion, tags, advertising, sponsored-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should tags that represent concepts be sponsorable?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33081/should-tags-that-represent-concepts-be-sponsorable)

Recently I've been observing the huge amount of tags Telerik is now sponsoring. My question is this: Is it right for a sponsored tag to sponsor unrelated things? For instance if for the tag C++ the sponsor was giving links to Delphi products. This is just an example but still.

The [`[cms]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cms) tag sponsored by Telerik is sponsoring nothing but Silverlight controls. I was not aware that CMS had anything to do with rich client side technologies. Is it right for things to be like this?

Comment: It might be effective to voice your interest here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33081/

Comment: http://www.sitefinity.com/

Comment: I think @Joel is feeling a bit grumpy this afternoon :)