# ASP.NET sponsorship

Tags: discussion, sponsored-tags

I'm not fussed if this gets closed or whatever, but seeing the DevExpress logo on the ASP.NET tag just makes me angry! I know they paid or chose and it's the same with all tags...but `asp.net` IS a Microsoft thing, and it's close to my heart...this is beyond `performance` being sponsored by [Red Gate Software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Gate_Software)...grrrrrrrrrrrrrr

C#, WinForms...ahhhhhhhhhhh

Looks like they have unsponsored the tags? yay!

Comment: Also visual studio, which is a microsoft PRODUCT

Comment: Probably best to redirect the rage here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33081/should-tags-that-represent-concepts-be-sponsorable

Answer (score 11, accepted):

David, you are not the only one.

What the hell are they thinking? Get rid of this crap.

We love SO for its cleanness and ease of use. It's a pleasure to work with the UI.

These adverts are horrible, please SO, don't ruin it with this barrage of advertising!