# New Icon for C# / .NET Tags

Tags: discussion, tags, sponsored-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do icons on the tags mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean)

Why is there a Dev Express logo on C# / .NET now? Are they sponsoring or something, I'm not really sure I like this change as it's mis-branding.

Answer (score 0):

**Companies can sponsor tags.**

See this [discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33081/should-tags-that-represent-concepts-be-sponsorable).