# Synonyms and icons for bug tracking tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, sponsored-tags

1. I think the [bug-tracking](/questions/tagged/bug-tracking) tag should be a
   synonym of the [issue-tracking](/questions/tagged/issue-tracking) tag.
2. I don't think that either of those tags should use the [youtrack](/questions/tagged/youtrack) tag's icon (unfair competition).
3. Should the [bug-tracker](/questions/tagged/bug-tracker) tag be a
   synonym too?

Comment: Agreed on point #1, but not sure what your point is on #2. Why shouldn't they?

Comment: @lear because it's not the only BTS http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue-tracking_systems

Answer (score 5):

> 1. [issue-tracking](/questions/tagged/issue-tracking) should be a synonym of [bug-tracking](/questions/tagged/bug-tracking)

With sufficient permissions, you can propose synonyms at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bug-tracking/synonyms.  I see no reason for this process to be overridden for a tag that's not *obviously* the *exact same thing*.

> 2. both tags shouldn't use the [youtrack](/questions/tagged/youtrack) icon

They use the icon because YouTrack sponsors those tags, not because StackOverflow just decided arbitrarily to associate the icon. [This is one way that StackOverflow makes money](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/30187/143601).

There is a lot of discussion about these topics in the [sponsored-tags](/questions/tagged/sponsored-tags) tag, including [Should tags that represent concepts be sponsorable?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/33081/143601)

I will add that it seems at least *some* tags can (apparently) gain sponsored links *without logos on the tags* — see [cms](/questions/tagged/cms)

Comment: in this particular case they shouldn't accept it // it makes sense for proprietary apps though (like google-chrome)

Comment: @Knu That's already been [amply discussed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33081/should-tags-that-represent-concepts-be-sponsorable)

Comment: @mrozek just discovered it […] btw is there a greasemonkey script for it?

Answer (score 1):

> [issue-tracking](/questions/tagged/issue-tracking) should be a synonym of [bug-tracking](/questions/tagged/bug-tracking)

**Issues are not bugs**, but bugs can be issues.

In a synonym relationship, [bug-tracking](/questions/tagged/bug-tracking) *could* be a synonym of [issue-tracking](/questions/tagged/issue-tracking), causing [issue-tracking](/questions/tagged/issue-tracking) to be the "parent" in the relationship.

Comment: good point Ill edit my question