# A comment about a duplicate should not be automatically added if there is already a comment pointing to the same question

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, automatic-comments

I voted to close [Why is there a NVIDIA logo in the [GPU] and [GPGPU] tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127163/why-is-there-a-nvidia-logo-in-the-gpu-and-gpgpu-tags) because I think it is a duplicate of another question, as pointed out by Robert Harvey in his comment.

Once I voted to close it, an automatic comment was added, even though there was already another comment pointing to the exact same question.

[image: screenshot]

I don't think the second comment should have been added in this case. That is what I have normally seen happening: When somebody already commented, and added a link to  the duplicated question, such as in "See also [link to question]." the automatic comment is not added.
In this case, I notice there is a slight difference between the link in the automatic comment, and the link in the existing comment: In the automatic comment, the link is `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33081/should-tags-that-represent-concepts-be-sponsorable`, while in the existing comment the link is `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33081`. This difference could explain the different behavior seen in this case; still, as the linked question in both the comments is the same, the system should detect this case.

In https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127210/how-to-repost-a-question the automatic link is not present because there is already a comment with a link to the duplicated question, which is [Getting attention for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-my-old-unanswered-questions)

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

I voted to close [Can I ask a question on gaming stackexchange about my own game and answer it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127206/can-i-ask-a-question-on-gaming-stackexchange-about-my-own-game-and-answer-it) as duplicate of a question pointed out in a comment; also in this case, the automatic comment is not added.

[image: screenshot]

In this case, the link used in the existing comment is `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking`, the same link the automatic comment will use.

Comment: I noticed this recently myself.  I thought it used to account for slightly-different links but maybe I'm just crazy.

Comment: I'm quite sure it's indeed the different URL causing this, as often I do NOT see a duplicate comment when I vote after someone else posted such links without voting. (As an aside: I like the way Robert just posts a link when wanting the community to decide, rather than using the moderator-one-vote-close! Sometimes he even uses a lowercase P `;-)`)

Comment: Robert's comment was not auto-inserted, so it doesn't look quite like the auto inserted one.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ: Correct;  I capitalize my phrases. :P

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ I know Robert's comment was no auto-inserted: If a moderator votes to close, the question is closed, and the automatic comment is not even added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I put my own "Possible Duplicate" link in a comment, because I didn't want to unilaterally close the question.  I wanted to see if it would get confirmation from at least one other community member.  Anyone else would simply vote to close.

So it's an edge case, having only to do with moderators refraining from exercising their unilateral close vote.

Comment: Another edge: Before I had enough reputation to vote to close, I would sometimes make similar comments as hints to those who could. (Flagging may be more useful, but as a lower-rep user I was more comfortable leaving comments than flagging, particularly after a couple of my initial flags were declined.)

Comment: And in addition to moderators and low-reputation users, there are people like me, who (at least on Stack Overflow) regularly consume all 50 of their close votes before they've wasted a day's worth of time on the site. I'm stuck leaving similar comments at that point as well.

Comment: Stil then: when using the exact same URL, no additional auto comment is inserted.  All the OP is asking: couldn't the same apply for similar URLs.

Comment: @Arjan: I thought that the algorithm detected already-existing links by matching the comment link, but apparently not.

Comment: I *think* it indeed detects links that are exactly the same, though I am not 100.00% sure. I also seem to recall that after editing an auto-inserted link, no second auto comment is added for subsequent votes. I even *think* that links to answers are recognized, and no auto comment is inserted. If all that is true, then somehow your short URL was missed. I noticed an edit pencil icon next to your comment. Any chance the URL was even worse at the time that kiamlaluno voted to close?

Comment: What I am saying is that the automatic comment should not have been added, because there was already a comment with a link to the same question. That is what normally happens; what could have confused the code is that the link are not exactly in the same format. It's not a edge case, and it's not limited to moderators; there are users who point a duplicate question without voting to close the question, for example in a comment like "See also [link to the question]."