# Can I ask a question on gaming stackexchange about my own game and answer it?

Tags: discussion

I have built a small puzzle game in my spare time.  I wanted to create general question about how to play the game and answer it myself.

A few notes:

- My Game is an iPhone app.
- The app will be free.
- My Game is not released yet - As a requisite for the Apple upload process I have to provide a support URL.  I dont have the time or the expertise to build my own site, I was hoping to link to a general question on how to play.

So will this be allowed?

Or will it be seen as a shameless attempt to promote my own stuff (which it partly is!)

Comment: You should be asking on [Meta Gaming](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/), we don't get to decide what the Gaming community finds acceptable and what not, we can only give you generic tips.

Comment: This is a mixed duplicate of: [Can I answer my own questions, even those where I knew the answer before asking?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking) and [Limits for self-promotion in answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers)

Comment: @YannisRizos Ok thanks, I didn't realize there was a meta for each site.

Comment: There are any number of services that will let you built a decent website without any expertise or much time.

Comment: @AlEverett Thats sounds great, could recommend one?

Comment: @Robert: You might be okay, as long as you don't give off a whiff of self promotion, other than a link in your profile...

Comment: Lets not migrate it.  I think the question was answered successfully.  You need to partner with SE if you want to use it as your support site.  Otherwise, get a UserVoice or a Blogger website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If nobody else can play the game currently, then you should not post questions about it. They aren't useful to anyone else at the moment and nobody can verify them.

Once the game is released, you can post questions about your own game on Gaming.SE, but you should clearly state your affiliation in your profile and be careful and considerate about it. Questions that are also self-promotional should meet a higher quality standard than other questions, else you'll quickly be suspected to be more interested in the promotion at the expense of the site itself.

**Stack Exchange sites are not a replacement for other support venues!** A large part of support requests are off-topic on Gaming.SE, e.g. bug reports. You shouldn't direct your users to post all their support questions on an SE site.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your response.  I dont suppose you could direct me to a support website that would be more suitable to my needs?

Comment: @Robert SE used [UserVoice](http://www.uservoice.com/) before meta was created, I haven't used it myself though.

Answer (score 1):

No, If the purpose is just to advertise or advocate your game.
Yes, If the purpose is to educate and provide information which might be useful for the users of the game development tag.

For ex:
The C++ community in SO specifically has an [c++-faq](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) for the latter.