# "Doris knows HTML5" - who is she?

Tags: discussion, tags, sponsored-tags

I just noticed that the [html5](/questions/tagged/html5) tag has a new icon:

[image: Doris knows HTML5]

I searched on Stack Overflow and Google for her. Apparently, she once showed up in an advert. Other than that, I know nothing about her. Who is Doris, and what's she doing on the HTML5 tag?

Comment: The icon on the tag was a mistake (and is fixed already) -- icons on tags only are allowed if the sponsor "owns" the tag. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33081/should-tags-that-represent-concepts-be-sponsorable/104757#104757.

Comment: If comments could be accepted, I'd pick yours @balpha. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Well, clicking the link leads to [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dorischen/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

@Bart covers the 'who' part of your question above, and @balpha addressed the why.

To reiterate: 
companies who sponsor tags only get the icon if they 'own' it. Which is to say, [html5](/questions/tagged/html5) will not have an icon, but [windows-8](/questions/tagged/windows-8) will, as it is a Microsoft product.

Also noted by @balpha, the error is now fixed. :)

Comment: I can't believe this got 11 upvotes and the accept without actually answering "Who is Doris."

Comment: Miss Gladys Stevens, who is 63 years old. She lives in Omaha.

Answer (score 23):

This particular tag has a sponsor, presumably Microsoft. Doris refers to Doris Chen, Developer Evangelist at Microsoft. The [first sponsored link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dorischen/) on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html?tab=Newest) leads to her blog.

Comment: You will also see "Daniel knows Windows Phone" - or at least you used to, and I know Daniel Egan who is pictured in the ad and recognized him. They are real people.

Comment: Thanks. I saw a blank space (Chrome), but after some F5 spamming, the links finally showed up. This is the first time that I see an individual being a sponsor. So, anyone can pick a popular/hot tag, and put their face on it?

Comment: I don't think the individual is a sponsor. I think Microsoft is and they chose to use particular people as a representative for the tags they sponsor.

Comment: You might also see 'Boris knows SFA'. I don't think it was sponsored by Microsoft though, I think it was Ken Livingstone.