# Who is Doris ? Why is she sponsoring HTML5?

Tags: discussion, sponsored-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Doris knows HTML5” - who is she?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149023/doris-knows-html5-who-is-she)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5

I mean, Google sponsoring Android, Chrome and Dart, MS doing it with Windows related technologies, Adobe advertising their stuff too. Cool.

But.. Doris ??? With all my respect to this good women, how is she related to HTML5 ? o_O

Quoting https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/33135/169519 - '*What will happen if Microsoft Sponsored the iPhone tab and put lot of link on how to developer for the Windows 7 Phone?*'

Comment: thanx for linking duplicate. Search was not returning anything, for some reason.

Comment: The duplicate was recently deleted. Since your question here it has been undeleted. So it couldn't have popped up in a search. ;)