# Is it possible to edit a tag and include an image?

Tags: support, tags, sponsored-tags

Some tags have small images against them (such as visual studio 2012). I was wondering is it possible to actually edit other tags and add images (i.e. adding the VS2010 logo to the visual studio 2010 tag)?

Comment: Those are sponsored tags.

Comment: @Bart Ah, so I'd have to pay to add that image to the VS tag?

Comment: @mattytommo no, I believe you have to own the rights - so it would be Microsoft that would have to pay

Comment: Well, you couldn't even do that. It would have to be MS themselves. They are the only ones eligible for that specific tag.

Comment: @Bart That's pretty poor really, it's only an image! IMO it makes the tags look nicer.

Comment: You can always contact MS and convince them. ;)

Comment: @mattytommo it's not meant to be nice, it's meant for advertisement.

Comment: See: [What do icons on the tags mean?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/30187)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tags like that are sponsored. That is, the companies behind those products/technologies have paid money to have that logo on them.

Even if you'd wish to do so, you could most likely not pay SO/SE to sponsor a specific tag. It would have to be Microsoft (in this case) who decides to do so. Some of the requirements [are listed here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104757/161198).