# Why does NVidia own the GPGPU tag, despite it not being in any way NVidia-specific?

Tags: discussion, sponsored-tags

General-Purpose GPU Computing is not a concept dominated purely by NVidia. It is somewhat abstract; there are multiple vendors/organizations/consortia involved in this field; and there's a popular non-NVidia GPGPU programming framework - OpenCL.

It thus appears that the GPGPU tag cannot be owned ("sponsored") by NVidia - according to the policy described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104757/196834).

So, how come I see the NVidia logo next to the GPGPU tag?

Comment: Because they payed good money for it. If you were SE, would you turn down free money?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: They must have paid very good money to get SE to break its own stated policy. To answer your question - yeah, of course I'd turn down that kind of money, this kind of tagging is a corrupting practice which annoys users (IMHO). Also, I believe 'free' and 'money' are two concepts which cannot coexist in the same sentence. See [this piece](http://www.amazon.com/Debt-The-First-000-Years/dp/1933633867) by anthropologist David Graeber if you're interested.

Comment: The fact is, Nvidia coined both terms, so they are both theirs to brand as they please. Seeing as this has been discussed before, regardless of what you think regarding 'corrupting practices' it's not changing. Money most likely was a large part of what went down, and I don't have an issue with that. Money makes the world go around, and if I have to see the logo of a company I like in the corner of a tag every so oft, no big deal.

Comment: GPU is just a generic-sounding acronym for devices which existed before the term was coined. And even that had not been the case, the fact that someone coind the term doesn't mean they own the concept. There's no "staking a claim" on ideas and concepts. As for having an issue with it - the official policy has an issue with it. So either that part of the policy is void, or the decision needs to be unmade. "Money makes the world go round"? Not much of an argument in my book.