# 'flex' tag no longer sponsored by Adobe?

Tags: support, questions, sponsored-tags

Did Adobe cancel their tag sponsorship?  I don't see their logo on flex/flash or anything else anymore but remember seeing it pretty recently.  I still see sponsored icons for android and sql-server.

Just curious.  I didn't see any posts about it here on meta (but lots of old posts complaining about the sponsorship and Adobe Flex vs Flex lexer..).

Comment: Looks like the term of the sponsorship just finished. These things cause more ruckus when new. Hardly a peep when they run the contract course.

Comment: I hope they're gone for good. Now just the BS ones on the SQL stuff next.

Comment: @Finglas, I liked the Adobe icons 'cause those tags were official Adobe products.  I agree with you on the SQL ones though.  red-gate is not really appropriate for those tags (red-gate does make good products though).

Comment: Gone the Adobe sponsorship may be, but it leaves us with a mis-named tag for the fast lexer as a legacy.

Comment: @dmckee, if only Vern had thought of trademarking "flex" when he wrote it...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adobe-sponsored tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23955/adobe-sponsored-tags)