# Has a change happened in the policy for sponsoring tags for abstract concepts?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, sponsored-tags

I have just remarked today that:

- Redgate still sponsors a few SQL Server tags, but they do not sponsor `performance` any more.
- Telerik (which was rather infamous for sponsoring tags such as `testing` and `unit-testing`) seems to no longer sponsor any tag.
- The only sponsored tag for an abstract concept I have seen would be `bug-tracking`.

I was wondering if there was a logic behind that situation - or if it was just a coincidence.

Anyway, I'll enjoy the absence of egregious tag sponsoring abuse while it lasts. :)

Comment: Maybe their subscriptions ran out

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have a new policy for sponsored tags: We're only allowing them from the trademark holder of the tag. The idea is, when we put an Android logo next to Android, or an Adobe logo next to Flex, people think it's cool. When we put a SmootzySoftware logo next to tags like "performance" people get somewhat… irked.

[Should tags that represent concepts be sponsorable?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33081/should-tags-that-represent-concepts-be-sponsorable)

Comment: Great to know. Is that change recent?

Comment: WOOHOO! VICTORY!

Comment: @Jean Hominal: The policy change started in the beginning of August.

Comment: +1 Good decision to tighten the reins on this. That said, I am still against sponsored tags in any form. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23955/adobe-sponsored-tags/24121#24121 Companys should definitely be able to choose tags for their ads to be associated with, but visually mixing the real content with advertising is always going to be a bad idea.