# OK to mention an Open Source project in SO post?

Tags: discussion, advertising, open-source, project

I am currently writing documentation and setting up a website for a open source PHP project under the LGPL - a very flexible content aggregator that for example can turn a XML datasource into a valid, cached RSS feed and much more. It was a paid project that the client has agreed to donate to the community with no strings attached.

- Will it be okay to promote this in a
  SO post in the form of a question
  (what do you think about..)?
- What other means of promoting an Open
  Source project do I have on SO?
- Where do I have to apply for donated
  ad space on SO as proposed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23899/proposal-free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects)?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646804/what-is-a-good-way-to-drum-up-interest-in-my-open-source-project

Answer (score 10):

> - Will it be okay to promote this in a SO post in the form of a question (what do you think about..)?

No, the community has almost always downvoted, closed, and deleted such 'questions.'

> - What other means of promoting an Open Source project do I have on SO?

Search for questions for which your project might be an answer.  Add more than "Refer to our project" - i.e., give a real answer and fit your project in as a possible solution.

> - Where do I have to apply for donated ad space on SO as proposed here?

As long as you fit the criteria listed in that question, send a message to team@stackoverflow.com for consideration.  Keep in mind that unless your project is sigificant and very useful to developers it probably won't get any free advertising.

Answer (score 8):

I wouldn't make a question just to promote it - it's likely to get flagged for spam. However, if you see a question where your tool is applicable, you could post it as an answer, but I would be sure to state your relationship with the project (full disclosure and all).

Answer (score 2):

You can promote it as an "*answer*" to a related question, but I don't think it should be asked as a question.

The answer should be useful for solving the question, or it will just get flagged as spam.

Comment: What if he makes clear his relation to the project?

Answer (score 2):

If it's a relevant answer to a question, I don't think it's a problem to mention it as long as you try to sound not too subjective.

Comment: I think you mean `s/not too//`.

Comment: No, he got it right the first time.

Comment: `s/try to sound not too/try not to sound too/`

Comment: @womble: he changed "objective" to "subjective" within the first five minutes ;)