# Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 1H 2010

Tags: discussion, open-source-advertising, crowdsourcing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 1H 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74983/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2011)

Here is your chance to create a [Free Vote-Based Advertisement for an Open Source Project](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23899/proposal-free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects). Create a graphical ad for an open source programming project and post it as an answer to this question (in the right format), and it will feed live remnant ads on [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com).

### Ad Requirements

It must be an advertisement **soliciting the participation and contribution of programmers writing actual source code**. This is not intended as a general purpose ad for consumer products which just happen to be open source. It's for finding programmers who will help contribute code or other programmery things (documentation, code review, bugfixes, etc).

In order to work, the answers you post to this question **must** conform to the following rules.

### Answer Template

```
[![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

  [1]: http://image-url
  [2]: http://clickthrough-url
```

Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to add any commentary, keep it in the comments.

### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220px by 220px**
- Can be hosted anywhere (tinypic, twitpic, your blog); we will mirror the image locally when we serve it.
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on filesize of ~150kb

The output, which ultimately will be served in an ad slot on Stack Overflow, can be previewed by clicking through to this URL:

http://rads.stackoverflow.com/ossads/220x250

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be served up by that URL and shown on Stack Overflow. You can see all the ads that currently make the threshold and meet our criteria on this page:

http://rads.stackoverflow.com/ossads/all

Comment: lol this question is already serving it's purpose. I'm curious about some of these projects I've never heard of before.

Comment: Will there be similar ones for the rest of the trilogy?  Apps like pidgin could go to superuser and serverfault could get admin-oriented tools.

Comment: Should the ads indicate what kind of help the project is looking for? Are ads for open-source programmer tools acceptable?

Comment: @Jeff. I think this is a wonderful scheme you have going here. The only thing is I find it frustrating to see the add and not have a explanation of what it is. I know you said this can be done via comments but it doesn't seem to be happening so far.

Comment: Can other sites run these ads? IE are they contributed beyond just stackoverflow?

Comment: +1 for @dlamblin You could easily provide listings for other websites.

Comment: Quibble on the format, but is it just Safari, Chrome and Firefox or does the "Tagline to show on mouseover" not show?

Comment: Is it just me, or are the majority of the ads here not an ad for programmers, but for a product?

Comment: R. Bemrose, one assumes that programmers would want to try the product *then* contribute to it. So the rule is, the project *must* allow outside code contributions and somewhat actively solicit outside code contributions.

Comment: @dlamblin: If you open up a new question called something like "running open source ads on 3rd party websites" we can start to flesh out how that would work. The initial problem is that the ad size on StackOverflow (220x250) is not an IAB standard and few websites (if any) will be able to use this size. But start the topic and let's try to figure out how to make it work.

Comment: It would be interesting to see a report comparing the effectiveness of the adds (how many people clicked on them) vs. how high they were voted. Are Meta user's effective add pickers or are they just oppinionated?

Comment: The ad I appreciated the most was the JQuerySharp. I think there's only one thing more motivating to a geek than to be addressed as "My Lord."

Comment: Just wondering: has the minimum score threshold been changed? Because there are two ads with 5 up votes that seem to meet the other criteria (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31913/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2010/38751#38751 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31913/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2010/38708#38708) but are not on http://rads.stackoverflow.com/ossads/all - or is some manual approval involved and it just takes some time?

Comment: I was going to update the info on the minimum score threshold to 6, based on what I observed to be the current value (see previous comment), but I got a message that I have to add some specific tags, which seemed wrong here.

Comment: @fabian try now

Comment: @Jeff: Worked this time, thanks.

Comment: Rather than adds for Open Source Projects, I'd really appreciate a list of projects that need help with a quick summary of what needs to be done in each one--what they are hoping to accomplish with this additional manpower.  If there is such a site, advertise that!

Comment: @billkressonaim: SourceForge comes to mind: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31913/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2010/40098#40098.

Comment: Are dupes with different ad images acceptable? Doesn't exactly seem fair to load up multiple ads for a single project and drown out others.

Answer (score 230):

[image: Synergy+. Connecting Computers.]

Comment: +1 synergy is great.  To quote a co-worker regarding his ability to control four computers in his home, "Now I never have to leave my bed!"

Comment: Yeah, it's amazing. I use it every day. Don't know what I would do without it! It's not in a great shape at the moment though and could really use some work, especially with the recent OS releases we have had.

Comment: I'd like to help, did you contact the original dev about forking it?

Comment: They're trying to get back in contact with original devs so it can be merged under one product/project.

Comment: I find the thing really stable. I use it everyday on all 3 platforms. Although it there are still a lot of bad edge cases to iron out.

Comment: I <3 synergy!
I thought it was a dead project though, so this is awesome!

Comment: I had no idea this even existed, thanks a lot!

Comment: Ohh haw many times have i bumped my mouse against the edge of the screen and stumbled back again... but I want the mouse on THAT computer... and why can't i click on my coffee mug!

Comment: oh *please*, I'd upvote this five times if I could.

Answer (score 227):

[image: SSH on Windows]

Comment: I think this doubles as an ad for figlet too.

Comment: I think you need to make it a bit more contrasty, love the ad and love putty

Comment: Maybe use `univers` for Putty, and use `thick` for the subtitle, although then you lose the joke on the `epic` font.  But those fonts are definitely higher-contrast.

Comment: I don't want to steal your idea, but here's my screencap with ANSI color added: http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/7831/puttyad.png

Comment: This is one of the projects for which I would have used an actual size capture of the upper left just after login. It's recognizable without the ascii art. I didn't know they actually needed developers though, which is what the advertising is about... so mission accomplished.

Comment: This one really got my attention

Comment: Putty FTW (15 chars)

Comment: This should go the way of Pidgin, along with winscp

Comment: Putty + Launchy + http://code.google.com/p/putty-launchy-plugin/ is a nice combo.

Comment: Hard to read image.

Comment: You know what, the reality is that this is by far the best ad when it comes to CTR. Don't change a thing!

Comment: Putty :x . FTW \m/

Comment: Huh. Are these fonts hinted?

Comment: Nice. But it is PuTTY, and perhaps it could better be served centered.

Comment: What would I do without PuTTY on Windows?  lol Pretty Epic.

Answer (score 224):

[image: jQuery]

Comment: I love jQuery as much as the next guy, probably more (I'm wearing a jQuery t-shirt right now and I made a project based on jQuery that I've posted in this thread). That said, do they really need the promotion?? Those guys are doing fine.

Comment: Was that the point of this?  I was was more about the humor.

Comment: I'm not sure making jQuery extensions is more fun than working (unless you're a Barista)

Comment: @Chris: I see you're trying to make coffee for an ungrateful rich yuppie. You should totally drop that and try JQuery instead.

Comment: Yaay, subshells!

Comment: When I first saw the ad, I thought it was about Prototype. $() isn't specific to jQuery, so you might want to mention jQuery somewhere in the ad.

Comment: @Charlie: It can be for Prototype too -- I'm easy.

Comment: jQuery is pretty neat, but it does bother me that it's been promoted like it's a done deal it won the JS framework wars - which is far from the case.

Comment: @cruachan No, no, no, no, no it's a done deal.  jQuery's won by a *long* shot.  When Microsoft tells you that they want to include your open source Javascript framework with the next release of their IDE, it's a done deal buddy.  Please believe.

Comment: Mootools didn't want to allow (read: put up with) new users in, and jQuery did. Done deal for people like me.

Comment: @John Sheedan I agree. jQuery is the best, but everyone already knows. Things like Django and big projects like that are where we need support.

Comment: @Chris Making espresso is a lot of fun. I'd do it for a living if it paid well. No joke.

Comment: @Charlie Agreed!

Comment: It saddens me that jQuery won the framework wars. I believe Prototype is far superior to jQuery.

Comment: @Charlie Somerville: Do you have any reasons for that statement?

Comment: jQuery make scripting more effective than ever :)

Comment: @Austin Kelley Way: I believe that you just can't go past the excellent documentation of Prototype. jQuery's pales in comparison

Comment: What is this font?

Comment: @marharepa : They are both Courier new.  The $() is bold and I believe the comment was set to not do Kerning -- but I'm not sure.  It was a while ago.  Also, I used an online "banner maker" and who knows exactly what they were doing.  (No, I don't remember which one.)

Comment: @Charlie Somerville:  To me the jQuery docs are way better...  For the record I was a big prototype fan before I ever heard about jQuery, and it took only about 2 weeks before I was a convert.  jQuery is, in my opinion, better in just about every way when it comes to writing webapps.   I also currently develop on WebOS, which uses prototype, so I still use both frameworks a lot.  Prototype has some nice features that jQuery doesn't, it's just that the core stuff that you use over and over is much more clumsy.   That said, I don't think jQuery needs these advertisements :)

Answer (score 171):

[image: Django: the web framework for perfectionists with deadlines]

Comment: This ad is 250x250 instead of 220x220, which is why it is not showing up.

Comment: @Portman: thank you for making me note this. I hadn't realized that I had used the wrong size.

Comment: What, no magic pony?

Comment: Feel free to ad another one :)
There is some whitespace that could be used.

Comment: There are some smudges on this image.

Comment: It should say: "Rails, without the Ruby... Or the suck".

Comment: Is is possible to change the size ?

Comment: Awful lot of space left over on the bottom... Instead of the detailed description (the tagline already tells us what django is), I'd add a call to action. 'Come help make the Web framework for perfectionists with deadlines even better!' Maybe a description of who you're looking for (Python devs?).

At the very least, capitalize 'high-level'. The inconsistency will drive me nuts.

Comment: @The Big Cheese - I agree with mllerustad. I think that a call to action will elicit more clicks to Django, which will create more Django developers.

Answer (score 162):

[image: The world's most advanced open source database.]

Comment: Done. logo source, font: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Image:PostgreSQL_logo.3colors.svg http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luxi_(fonts)

Comment: +1, love the "JOIN us" statement.

Answer (score 128):

[image: Legendary hackers hack on Emacs]

Comment: I know, explaining jokes should be unnecessary, but for those who don't get it: http://xkcd.com/378/

Comment: Also: *scratch* (the buffer name) is a pun on scratching your own itches. And '(Lisp)' (the major mode), is in parens, ahem...  And 'legendary': you have to assign copyright to the FSF to have your code accepted into Emacs, so you end up on the Roll Call of Honour: a Legend. Or something...

Comment: Uhm, vim fans are going to vote it down :D

Comment: This is a great ad. Colorful, easy-to-read text, in-jokes but you don't have to get them to get the gist of the ad... I might make 'Legendary hackers Hack on Emacs' in bold to put the emphasis of the ad there, but it's good as is.

Comment: btw, what window manager is that from?

Comment: EMACS MUST WIN. I do not have enough rep but just signed in to voice my vote, even if I am not rich enough to make it count.

Comment: @mlvljr: do you want to know the window manager, or the theme?-)

Comment: @tzot what's the theme?

Answer (score 125):

[image: Help people communicate with Pidgin!]

Comment: Be merciful, I'm a programmer, not a designer...

Comment: +1 from me. Great bit of OS software

Comment: Great product, but the ad would be better layed out if the pidgeon was on the right looking left. A user looking at the page will see the pidgeon first, follow the pidgeon's eyes, see your tagline (this is good) and then see the edge of the page (this is not so good). This only happens because the advert is placed on the right of the page. The whole page and your advert would feel more ballanced if the user's eye went from pidgeon, to tagline, to the rest of the page.

Comment: I use it, but I would like to see more frameworks and libraries than applications in the ads

Comment: @Jader Dias Well, to be technical Pidgin is based on the LibPurple library for chat communication, but I thought it'd be harder to make an add for the library.

Comment: I agree with all that @Richard said, just reversing the placement of the bird would reverse the flow of the ad and create contrast, drawing the eyes along the tag line. Good ad otherwise! I love Pidgin, and developing for them would be something I'd love to do, should they be looking to expand into the iPhone market! Who's with me; an iPhone app would be stellar.

Comment: ...is...that... is that a [Goodfeather??](http://www.jambitz.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/goodfeathers.jpg)

Comment: @danbirlem Excellent idea.

Comment: The bird is cute!

Answer (score 117):

[image: Python Programming Language]

Answer (score 94):

[image: Pygame - Python Game Library]

Comment: +1 love the control at the snake's mouth

Comment: pygame - great framework, horrible logo, classic :)

Answer (score 94):

[image: SQLite]

Comment: Not sure if they are needing developers, do your justice.

Comment: I think it's fine. SQLite is great, and anyone using it (i.e. programming with it) might end up finding bugs, writing blog posts with tips, etc. I consider that a valid interpretation of the rules. +1

Comment: +1, As far as licensing goes, SQLite is one of the most generous projects that exists. Its also very well maintained, documented and lets not forget its usefulness!

Comment: for some reason I saw trumpets spelling the word Jazz in a strangely calligraphy, until I moved away from the screen a bit and saw the feather :)

Answer (score 92):

[image: Sugar interface for OLPC]

Comment: This is a FANTASTIC cause, but that picture needs work

Comment: This is a FANTASTIC picture.

Comment: The photo is great, it's the rest of the ad (the whole image/'picture') that's the problem. The text isn't clear enough, especially the "OLPC" which is kind of the whole point. Also I'm not sure about the green borders etc.

Comment: Re: OLPC text is unclear; this is simply the location of the photo itself, which is CC-By licensed. You are supposed to be enticed to click the add, not read the small print :-)

Comment: Everyone except developers, the target audience?

Comment: You need a pic of a kid who doesn't look like he's on drugz. This is the most unappealing pic on the whole page.

Comment: Ad needs work, but it's definitely a worthy cause, so still gets my vote

Comment: Also, the link between the ad and the destination isn't totally clear - I expected to see something about education in africa, OLPC or whatever - you at least need the logo for the destination site on the banner.

Comment: @everybody: I think most people will know what this is referring to even without clicking the link or seeing the URL.  I just came across it, and I felt like it "worked".

Answer (score 84):

[image: See...there are some practical applications of genetic algorithms after all.]

Comment: Apologies for the Northern Hemisphere bias.

Comment: +1 for the rip on ID. And for it being a great add. And cool product. Wait that's +3!

Comment: Would be nice if the link worked...

Comment: @Joel: Works for me.

Comment: @Portman: I didn't see it as a rip on ID; it sounds more like "Even evolutionary algorithms need to be designed." (Even though I've read uncommons.org before and I know it was likely meant as a rip.)

Comment: To be honest, I don't care about the Intelligent Design debate.  Evolutionary algorithms work whether you believe in evolution in nature or not.  One of the distinctive features of Watchmaker compared to other Java programs is its design.  Specifically the way it uses generics and does not require the evolved type to be coupled to any framework classes or interfaces.  On occasion I have used the term "intelligent design" to get this point across, playing on the double meaning of the term in this context.

Comment: This ad will make no sense at all in the summer.

Comment: It's autumn here.

Comment: simple design, good typography, great copy/text +1

Comment: @Dan the funny point is that evolution works whether you believe in it or not – just like the Watchmaker framework. ;-)

Answer (score 81):

[image: FileZilla]

Comment: Had Fire Rodan in there for a minute, but it got too crowded.

Comment: Who needs FileZilla when you can have WinSCP? :P

Comment: @Alix Axel  I haven't tried WinSCP, but FileZilla releases updates all the time, has an easy updater that takes like 30 seconds, supports SFTP, has a great site manager for storing sites, allows you to back everything up in JSON format, supports all the normal stuff like custom ports and passive FTP, and it's blazingly fast.

Comment: Oops forgot... They have a client, and a server, both equally awesome, an awesome logo, and a cool name.

Comment: I know, I've used it before. That's why I'm saying I preffer WinSCP! =D

Comment: @Alix: FileZilla is cross-platform. And from screenshots, WinSCP has a much worse interface.

Comment: @orokusaki Are they actually looking for developers? Seems to me everyone in this thread keeps posting their favourite open source apps without knowing whether they accept help or not.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat I don't know to be honest. I thought all open source projects needed help, but I don't seem to find anything about it on their site now that you mention it. I figured since I've been using it for like 3 years I'd better do my part (I certainly am not learning C any time soon so this is it for me).

Comment: Based ony my experience WinSCP is horrible and can't transfer files properly at all. I'll definately try FileZilla one of these days as a replacement for it.

Comment: @orokusaki You're right, all FOSS projects can use help. Just from my experience of a few apps, the developers seem reticent to take suggestions on board. I'll stop complaining now since this is not directed at FZ really :p

Comment: Filezilla is just awesome. I'd never use anything else.

Comment: Great stamp, but that is one weird silhouette :)

Comment: @George, lol, when it had Fire Rodan in the background behind Godzilla it was even weirder.

Comment: The letters are big /
I am a bad haiku scribe /
I weep for myself

Comment: FileZilla is good, but its interface is a horrible mess.

Answer (score 81):

[image: Notepad++]

Comment: Needs a better image.

Comment: @Justin Nelson - jjnguy: Updated it.

Comment: @Alix Looks way better.

Comment: @Alix: are they taking contributions? I had added a Notepad++ ad, but deleted it after somebody pointed to me that the original developer wasn't taking code.

Comment: @voyager: I'm not sure if he accepts core code, but AFAIK plugins, syntax highlighters, themes and translations are welcome.

Comment: They really need help on their site. No script, tough luck. It's also getting old that every update disables all the existing plug-ins.

Comment: I which I knew how to make this editor work within Visual Studio

Comment: More than anything, Notepad++ needs UI improvement.

Comment: One of the worst logos I've seen so far, and usually developers don't even bother much. Horrible colours and the software reminds of sciTe, only I like sciTe better -1. I am horrible, I know.

Comment: @George: I agree with you on everything, except the sciTE being better.

Comment: This editor is promising on many levels, but, in addition to some of the drawbackss mentioned above, this one IMHO needs the touch of someone with really good design sensibilities, and it would be great if it were scriptable in a higher-level language such as javascript, python or ruby (see e.g., Sublime text editor for a comparison http://www.sublimetext.com/).

Comment: Notepad2 much better.

Comment: @stacker: I don't agree.

Comment: @Alix Axel I also agree with you, except I didn't say sciTE is better, it's just me just me that likes it better :P

Answer (score 79):

[image: I like to move it move it]

Comment: I'm a crappy graphic designer, I encourage others to make ads for putty and winscp.  Shop my images if you wish.

Comment: Product ad, not a call for developers.

Comment: I made two variations based on the logo and colours on your web site: http://www.pekkagaiser.com/stuff/winscp1.png http://www.pekkagaiser.com/stuff/winscp2.png Feel free to use them if you like them.

Comment: image doesn't help.

Answer (score 78):

[image: jQuery Timeago: your server output cache will thank you]

Comment: Looks like an interesting project, but I object to the "one line of jQuery" part. It's meaningless - anything can be "one line" if you're just calling another function...

Comment: Heh, it's cool seeing my little project make this list.  Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't "Try it!" be more like "Help us write it!"?  As-is, seems to be advertising the product rather than soliciting development as an open project.  Though it appears this is a common issue (but "try it" overemphasizes it, perhaps?), isn't the request for ads "soliciting the participation and contribution"?  Have I misunderstood?

Comment: Roger, You have to try it before you would ever consider contributing.  The more people that use a project, the more likely someone will come along to help out with it.

Comment: Ryan: that argument doesn't seem to work for some ads: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31913/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2010/31933#31933 I like the concept of timeago and I'm glad to have found out about it through this Q, just trying to improve the ad.

Comment: Irony: http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/1722-general/suggestions/96770-auto-update-the-fuzzy-timestamps-with-jquery-timeago-

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat - no, one line is still important when you're asking someone to implement your code. One added line is tremendously easier to ask for as compared to 10 lines involving configuration and conditional calls.

Comment: @jsoverson: I see what you're getting at, but like I said, you can make any code "one line", whether it's one function of a whole lotta config. Practically all jQuery plugins are one line anyway, plus you also need to include jQuery and the plugin code and some `document.ready` code, so it's far from your definition of "one line" anyway.

Comment: anyone else sees a hand with 3 uniformly fading fingers, which one would expect to fade incrementally for some reason ?

Comment: Wow, this page called me a loser

Answer (score 72):

[image: How do you implement full-text search for that 10+ million row table, keep up with the load, and stay relevant? Sphinx is good at those kinds of riddles.]

Comment: Sphinx is an important part of my site - I figured that this would be a nice way to thank the developers.

Comment: PS - the art is a legit purchase from iStockphoto and legal to use in a digital advertisement.

Comment: Sphinx rules! very professional looking ad.

Comment: Can't vote this one up because I'm too new on meta :(

Comment: very professional, but it doesn't actually show a sphinx.  silhouettes of egyptian gods aren't really the same thing.

Comment: I'm a fan of Sphinx

Comment: This is confusing, I thought it was for sphinx the python documentation engine http://sphinx.pocoo.org/

Comment: nice illustration

Answer (score 66):

[image: Firebird RDBMS - Simple, Powerful, Scalable, Fast - Join us]

Comment: Big thanks to Carlos Cantu for the banner design.

Comment: While there might be FB users on SO, I don't see a good way to tell them to come to meta.

Comment: I came here for the Watchmaker framework ad and stayed for the JQuerySharp ad. :) But it so happens I'm a fan of Firebird too.

Answer (score 62):

[image: RestSharp: .NET REST Client]

Comment: beautiful sign }# - rest sharp!

Comment: Yay! This is nice. So many people (at least in Sweden) don't get that it is a sharp sign, not a "quadruple plus" or something. Here it is obvious. Great ad!

Comment: I figured anyone who could recognize a rest symbol would also recognize the sharp....

Comment: I'm not sure I like the "Fork it." statement. I know what it means, many developers who come here will know what it means, but it still sounds almost insulting, and more so to people who don't know the technical term "fork".

Comment: knife it. stab it. tooth it.. :)

Comment: "Fork it" / "Fork me" was stupid to begin with and now it's just getting really old.

Comment: Simple and effective +1

Answer (score 58):

[image: Contribute to Eclipse]

Comment: Add a impacting phrase will make the Ad much more interesting.

Comment: @Nathan: I was considering that, but didn't have anything witty on my mind. And the official phrases don't seem perfect in this context either, as I feel *Contribute to Eclipse* is a bit dull here and *Get involved!* of course is too generic. So I decided to stick to just the official logo in its current state for now. Also, I think there is reason to hope the logo will be easily recognized by people that could be interested in contributing to Eclipse.

Comment: You need to let people know you are asking for help though. No one is going to click on it (even if it just "Eclipse") if you don't.

Comment: @Austin: Yes true, added a caption. Thanks, also @Nathan.

Comment: [Eclipse Logo]
Don't scream at it - help us make it screaming fast!

Comment: not very original, but quite ok.

Answer (score 57):

[image: Drupal.org: when you can't pin all the blame on PHP.]

Comment: plz send us the developers!!!1

Comment: Re: point 2: the move to Git is underway.

Comment: Hilarous (and unfortunately accurate). Still, it may annoy Drupal more than help them.

Comment: Downvote. This is not what ads are for.

Comment: Too many words!

Comment: I've been using *(and developping for/with)* Drupal for almost 10 months, and what this "ad" says is, unfortunatly, true... But I really don't think this will attract developpers that could help the project : as a PHP developper, I don't want to go develop Drupal when I see this *(Even if I know some nice things can be done with it -- imagine if I didn't know...)*

Comment: Nice things can be done with Drupal, and nice things can be said about Drupal, but the spaghetti behind the scenes and other "inconvenient truths" are just bubbling beneath the surface. This ad is just one tiny attempt to address the issue with some humor, instead of ignoring it, and letting good developers abandon the project because they think everyone must be happy with the status quo.

Comment: -1 for completely missing the SO freehand circle meme.

Comment: Meh, this ad sucks. It's trying to hard to be ironic.

Comment: Yes, insulting the project is a terribly mature way to help Drupal.

Comment: @John Fiala: Sometimes that's the best way to motivate somebody to fix their stuff the heck up - and as an advert, it lets a potential programmer know what they're getting in to, so they're less likely to simply leave when they see the project from the inside. Now -that- is a bad way to help :P

Comment: Why drive developers to a project that produces developers frustrated enough to make this kind of ad? Because 29 people liked it? Antagonizing something is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: @Tim Post probably more like 43 people upvoted and 14 people downvoted (assuming a 1:1 mapping between votes and people).

Comment: This is the most hilarious advert I have seen in my life. When you get used to hacking around with the quirky user interface, you can do a huge amount on Drupal without writing a single line of code. But the second you want to start writing code, OH NO!

Comment: Nice! You need to be honest with developers. They will dig the truth anyway. And leave.. =)

Comment: downvoting also. this is an open source project, so you can help improving it. if you don't want (or aren't able) to do so, just leave it alone. but don't be childish and post such an insulting ad. that's not what SO's OS ads are ment for: *It must be an advertisement soliciting the participation and contribution of programmers writing actual source code*.

Comment: @ax: I respect your viewpoints. Nevertheless, the ad says "please help" and links to drupal contribute: 100% meeting the ad requirements. ALSO, nowhere does it say Drupal is a "crappy" CMS. There no denying there is some very un-pretty spaghetti in there though, many Drupal veterans make this point themselves on blogs and in archives of past Drupalcons on screencast

Comment: @ax: oh - and lots of people use MSFT Windows as well. That alone doesn't mean it is perfect and cannot be improved upon. Lots of people use duct tape to repair furniture, fix plumbing and make wallets, that alone does not prove it is the optimal solution.

Comment: @dreftymac: as others point out in the comments, this ad *does not* help bringing new contributors to the Drupal project. which is what SO OSS ads are meant for. that's my whole point, and that's why i think this ad should be removed.

Comment: scary...it's so bad, it's good! :)

Comment: -1 This ad completely drove me away from Drupal. I haven't worked with it much, but now I probably never will. Watching a development community whine about their bad code really doesn't inspire me to join the project...

Comment: It's most likely not going to help at all, but I have to say, it's the first ad that's motivated me to click on it.

Comment: +1 This ad completely drove me away from Drupal. Which is good, because I avoided using a horrible CMS when far better alternatives are available. Thanks for the warning!

Comment: @JohnFiala: It's called trolling, and this ad is a nice example of how trolling can be used for good as well as evil ;-).

Answer (score 56):

[image: Kernel Newbies: gotta start somewhere]

Comment: He looks like a shinier Alan Moore.

Comment: Is Alan's face the best way to promote kernel hacking?

Comment: Yeah, this isn't ideal. I was originally going to have it say "Newbies Wanted" but that seemed to much like taking the piss, where as I just wanted to poke gentle fun. It was then going to be a playing card: Kernel Hacker Cards, collect them all, but I didn't like the suite emblems in each corner. I guess I removed too much and it's now just a man with a beard. Oh well, maybe some one else will be inspired to try harder.

Comment: This guy is like a god to me!

Comment: if the Evony clone is disallowed, this should be disallowed as well!

Comment: Did anyone else have a "Shining" moment when this popped up in SO?  *Heeere's Johnny!*  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081505/quotes, http://www.imdb.com/media/rm3631716352/tt0081505

Comment: AFAICS this advert has the best click-through rate of the adverts right now. Alan must have a friendly face :)

Comment: I agree with the Shining quote. I didn't click on it until i read these comments because and was still fuzzy on what this was actually for. This add and dancing baby mortgage adjustment ads may have high click though but they are more smoke than genuine interest. The project is cool, it deserves a better ad.

Comment: This ad is so conspicious that I just had to click on it! And then I checked the text below the ad and it lead me to this page and learn to know about the OS ads. So it must be good.

Comment: For some reason this looks more like *"Alan Cox - R.I.P."* to me.

Comment: This is probably the most effective image in terms of getting clickthroughs. I know I've clicked it before, just because Alan Cox's face is so damn *alluring*.

Comment: It's a fan boy poster in a man crush sort of way. Unnerving at best. My mind keeps asking: upon clicking, will this picture invite me to the gates of kernel hacking or the gates of Hades?

Comment: I think Alan Cox wants to sex me.

Comment: like Tux was even necessary :)

Comment: Awesome.  That is all.

Comment: This really needs a better tagline.

Answer (score 52):

[image: Get started with hacking on GHC!]

Comment: http://imgur.com/MxSqK.gif
What do you think of this, gbacon? The one you posted is really blurry.

Comment: @Austin Animation is verboten.

Comment: cool image/lambda reference.

Comment: Not sure if the glossy gradient and the drop shadow was necessary. Clever symbol though.

Comment: @chakrit: Isn't that just a rendition of the Haskell logo? (Which is a cross between a lambda and ">>=" (which is pronounced bind).)

Comment: @AustinKelleyWay: The "cursor visible" frame would probably work nicely as a still, though!

Answer (score 45):

[image: Of course you'll run NetBSD]

Comment: I think "How can I help" is all that is needed here.. the tiny text should be axed, and the flag and "how can I help" made larger

Comment: Okay; the old one is at: http://i48.tinypic.com/2dah88x.png I just took it from http://netbsd.org/gallery/advocacy/flyer.pdf because there isn't really a great landing page for recruitment as such.

Comment: not in balance, also, have I seen this orange/gray logo combination before in the world of software ? hmmm...

Answer (score 45):

[image: Clojure is looking for contributors and programmers.]

Comment: My potentially lousy attempt at creating a nice ad for Clojure. Comments appreciated.

Comment: I'd move the "it" into the next line, so the lines are more visually balanced.

Comment: Unless you wanted to emphasise the "wrong", in which case, shrink the text on the line above it. :-)

Comment: Up yours, buddy!  Your momma did it wrong!

Comment: Hmm. Some people might get confused and think it's just that they aren't doing state the right way, rather than realize that state is the *wrong* way...

Comment: hate that j. interesting colours, but what's up with that logo, I mean I'm not sure if it's trying to be a tnuva(http://www.tnuva.co.il/site/EN/tnuva.asp?pi=20) or a scheme logo(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/PltSchemeLogo.gif)...I'm talking about colour distribution, not just the lambda in a circle

Comment: @SamB For those people, there's clojure tutorials?

Answer (score 43):

[image: Ruby on Rails - we are in beta! help, docs, patches are welcome!]

Comment: Ruby on Rails - few weeks to rails3 beta! help, docs, patches are welcome!

Comment: I've never really understood why Ruby on Rails' logo looks more like a strip of film than a railroad. Maybe it should be Ruby on Film Location which could be shortened to ROFL.

Comment: I always thought it looked like the tentacle things from Half-Life.

Comment: Looks like a wizard hat to me. I like it!

Comment: To report a bug and/or submit a patch: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/tickets

Comment: @orokusaki, me neither, but it makes the logo awesome. Literal rails might not reach most people. Don't like the orange background and the second ruby. Clean white background might have worked better (cleaner, nicely aired out)

Answer (score 43):

[image: The R-Project for Statistical Computing]

Comment: SOMEBODY set us up the bomb!

Comment: @JD Long: No, "somebody set up us the bomb". :-P Don't swap the "up" and "us" around! :-)

Comment: Logo is tacky. Hey 1991, we have internet webpage.

Comment: @macek: I agree, but that's what we have to live with...

Comment: Although the logo might safely ride with Michael J Fox straight Back to the Future, I think that's a strong point, as I read: "to busy with the Maths, don't care about the logo, don't need to." For some reason, the nerdier the logo is in a scientific software, the more I believe in the app. +1

Comment: Can't search R on Stack Overflow!

Comment: @ilhan: sure you can; just enter [r] into the search window.  It's a very popular tag.

Comment: I actually think the logo looks pretty nice. It's certainly a lot better than Haskell's old one was! (Man that thing was so busy...)

Answer (score 42):

[image: Life's basic utilities. You depend on them, they depend on you]

Comment: Is `poor` vs `pour` a pun on users of ext2fs?

Comment: It is a pun on anyone who sees a message with 'fsck' in it in general, because at that moment you're fsck'd. I had originally thought fsck on Linux was part of a general utilities package, and that's what I was advertising, but actually it is it's own package: e2fsprogs. Oh well, I think people still get the idea, and it is moderately amusing...

Comment: Ted Ts'o will give you a big hug for this. e2fsprogs are anything but rewarding to maintain.

Comment: got the fancy fcuk and other fashion references, but the poor homme in a domain dominated by males, that seems a bit much, if not sexist...and it could not even be intentional. like the discreet poor/pour thing though.

Answer (score 38):

[image: SciPy, the Matlab Killer]

Comment: Sorry, I could not find a better image. I am not even associated with the project, but I LOVE IT and I hope someone comes up with a better logo.

Comment: Please correct to the specified format.

Comment: @waiwai933: Fixed image.

Comment: How did this get the huge number of votes on the listing?

Comment: Fun logo, totally needs a call to action.

Answer (score 37):

[Castle Project http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/8121/text2924821.png](http://www.castleproject.org/community/getinvolved.html)

Comment: ImageShack seems to have deleted your image and [replaced it with an ad of their own.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263771) If you can reupload it, please do so; otherwise please consider deleting this answer.

Answer (score 33):

[image: The elegant MVC framework]

Comment: did you go to the "accounts" tab and associate your accounts? the system tells you to do this when you create a new account.. it also helps to use a stable openid (eg not google gmail) that works across domains.

Comment: Thanks for the help Jeff. Also, one quick question, what is the problem with using a Google openid?

Comment: Google OpenID creates a per-domain hash, which makes it a bit difficult for them to line up accounts across the sites. @aus

Comment: "fixxit" --> "fix it"

Comment: @mllerustad: it's intentional...

Answer (score 32):

[image: Project Help Wanted @ SourceForge.net]

Comment: source forge blocks some countries .. not so "open"

Comment: @hasen j: Never heard of that before.

Comment: @hasen j, @Alix: Not really their choice. Stupid US export laws...

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote this everytime I have to put up with their atrocious site design.

Answer (score 31):

[Moose is a postmodern object system for Perl 5 that takes the tedium out of writing object-oriented Perl. It borrows all the best features from Perl 6, CLOS (LISP), Smalltalk, Java, BETA, OCaml, Ruby and more, while still keeping true to its Perl 5 roots.  http://naraka.pauleira.com/moose/stackoverflow-moose-ad.png](http://moose.perl.org)

Comment: I *knew* Perl was a psychedelic language. :) Looking very nice and I guess the colourfulness is in keeping with the slogan!

Comment: I'm guessing post(MO)dern (O)bject (S)yst(E)m

Comment: nice graphics, but I'm sure the background painting is copyrighted (and on exhibit at the Hirhhorn, but I forget the artist's name)

Answer (score 29):

[MooRTE: Rich Text Editor Framework - IFrame Free WYSIWYG Editor http://img168.imageshack.us/img168/3008/moorteado.png](http://mootools.net/forge/p/moorte)

Comment: Note: this ad is 220px × 229px. Needs to be 220x220 for the ad to actually be served.

Comment: Resized ad to 220x220 (moved text up a bit to accommodate)

Comment: People will not read all that text. Make a simple sexy graphical image with a simple message instead.

Comment: No iFrame you say?

Comment: @user141287 I dunno, it IS an ad for a text editor. I like that it's specific about what dev help it needs--most of the ads here are missing that.

Comment: @SeanJA - correct - no iFrame.  Very flexible. Hope to have some big updates soon. Specially if this ad pulls in anyone :).                    

@dbr, I am assuming this ad will be served, coorect?

Comment: @samgoody: It seems likely (he says after following the "like" link under the ad)

Comment: You should disable inline spell checking for that screenshot.

Comment: @Nicolas: inline spell checking adds another level of realness - I love it.

Comment: @JohnK: It might be better if JavaScript was spelled correctly, though -- Chrome, at least, believes it should have a capital S.

Answer (score 28):

[image: Tweetsharp - A .Net Fluent Interface for the Twitter API]

Comment: Good library..I used it with a mapping app I built. 

http://donnyvblog.blogspot.com/2009/11/tweetgis.html

Comment: No! Twitter does not belong in ***everything***!!

Answer (score 28):

[image: The elegant MVC framework for Perl]

Comment: Wrong dimensions.

Comment: http://imgur.com/sG9kz.png This version should be correct, if someone want to switch them.

Comment: @Austin Kelley Way: Just did.

Comment: What's the programming language for that? I spend about 10 clicks on that link and I never was able to figure out!

Comment: @Oscar: Since CPAN is mentioned on the front page, I guess it's Perl.

Comment: Yup Perl should be mentioned :/
But you see they are referring to mod_perl

Answer (score 26):

[image: Pidgin - IM Client]

Comment: Another one for Pidgin?

Comment: @Wayne Koorts: Sorry, I've only noticed the disallowed ad. Should I delete this?

Comment: @Alix, I wouldn't. The other one was disallowed because it seemed a bit too much like an ad for the app, not an ad to encourage development for the app.

Comment: @voyager: Yeah, but it seems that a valid ad for Pidgin was already posted: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31913/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2010/34302#34302

Comment: @Alix, sorry forgot about that one. May be let the community decide which one to be used? If Jeff doesn't like it, he will take care of it :)

Comment: Obviously, it looks like an ad for the app. However, since it is a great one, it should be encouraged.

Answer (score 25):

[Ample SDK - Open-Source JavaScript GUI Framework http://www.amplesdk.com/share/banners/AmpleSDK_SO.gif](http://www.amplesdk.com/)

Answer (score 25):

[OpenHatch: the open source involvement engine! http://littlegreenriver.com/openhatchad.png](https://openhatch.org/search/)

Comment: aw, baby penguins!

Comment: The poor site itself needs help. returns 500 at the time of writing

Answer (score 24):

[Perl Application Development and Refactoring Environment http://naraka.pauleira.com/moose/stackoverflow-padre-ad3.png](http://padre.perlide.org/)

Comment: Maybe there should be a call for action on the logo. What about this one? "Hack your editor in your mother tongue."

Comment: That only works if you learned perl on your mother's knee...

Comment: It is beautiful, but some other softwares use the same blue butterfly (I think it is very rich now :) ). Use another animal that when people think about will remember of your product. I think more text is necessary, but at right-bottom corner with the smallest readable font.

Answer (score 23):

[Media Browser http://community.mediabrowser.tv/uploads/site_1/81/mediabrowser2.png](http://community.mediabrowser.tv/topics/942?response_type=7)

Comment: Feedback and ideas to improve this are more than welcome.

Comment: why not modify one of the "fan icons" on your web site and turn it into an ad? They look *great*.

Comment: I took the liberty of making two suggestions based on your artowrk on the site. Feel free to use it if you like. http://www.pekkagaiser.com/stuff/mediabrowser1.png http://www.pekkagaiser.com/stuff/mediabrowser2.png

Comment: @Pekka! You rule! I updated the Ad! Thanks heaps

Answer (score 23):

[Assaultcube Game Engine http://xeoncross.com/images/frag_crossing_220x220px.gif](http://assault.cubers.net/)

Comment: Real game engine code, relaxing social activity.

Comment: this seems like an ad for a game, not a call for programmers to contribute

Comment: They don't need more players, they need more people interested in working on the game engine.

Comment: +1 Agree totally with **Xeoncross**!

Comment: When I first saw this I was wondering why a game would advertise on SO.. didn't look programming to me at all

Comment: their website is awful

Comment: I know this says horrible things about me, but when this ad comes up in my peripheral vision, my eyes flick over to it and read "Fag Crossing" with a crosshair on a running person.  I'm pretty sure that this isn't SUPPOSED to be making me think of homophobic rednecks but....

Comment: @ttmrichter: agree completely. Anyone having looked into marketing knows that adverts are normally fast read, thus, are often misread the first time so you have to be really careful about what words you use. That, together with the use of nazi red and black colours only is an awful combo. Yeah it gets attention very well, but not the attention the project deserves...

Comment: Not obvious at all what it's for...

Comment: @Alex Nazi red? You mean, a full red? I think you're overthinking things a little too much, I didn't look at it and think "OMG, that's a swastika". Agree on the text though.

Answer (score 22):

[Help build KDE http://img88.imageshack.us/img88/7898/kdelogoadwhite.png](http://techbase.kde.org/Welcome_to_KDE_TechBase)

Comment: Favorized this over the other, because here the blue KDE logo is better distinguishable.

Comment: @Boldewyn: the only thing that I'm not completely happy with on this one is the Black text with a shadow, which on the other one seemed nicer. Any advice welcomed.

Comment: Is this ad about contributing to KDE (that sounds way too broad) or contributing to the documentation hosted on Techbase? :/

Comment: ImageShack seems to have deleted your image and [replaced it with an ad of their own.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263771) If you can reupload it, please do so; otherwise please consider deleting this answer.

Answer (score 21):

[image: The R-Project for Statistical Computing]

Comment: more slogan options: R: Pirate for Statistics! // R: SAS Should Have Seen This Coming // R: All Your Stats R Belong To Us! // R: Because Every Time You Use SPSS IBM Kills A Kitten.

Comment: Those are great!  I'll post those later, or feel free to do it yourself...

Comment: This slogan is ridiculously good in a nonsensical matter.

Comment: Also, *Stats'R'Us*?

Comment: This is a pretty well-known R slogan.  Because R is derived from the S language and is one letter over.  If you shift IBM by one letter you get HAL, the name of the 2001 AI computer.  Of course R is probably also derived from the fact that the two creators' first names both start with "R".

Answer (score 19):

[image: WPF Reports: Simple Open Source Reports for your XAML]

Comment: Simple and beautiful, ad & project +MaxHeight

Comment: +1 for the project. A bit of colour scale on the grey background would be nice

Answer (score 19):

[image: CKEditor - The Text Editor for the Internet]

Comment: Glad they decided to drop the F...

Comment: Is this a call for developers though?

Comment: @Pekka: Not a very clear one!

Comment: This is very nice, but too un-actionable. Should I contribute to it? Should I download it? Is it even free? (I know the answers, but they are not obvious from the ad as seen on the site).

Answer (score 17):

**editorial: disallowed** -- this is not an ad for programmers, but for a product.

[image: IM all your friends in one place]

Comment: is this really a "developer" thing though? Seems more like an ad for the client software than the fact that it's OSS you can hack on..

Comment: Damn! I just read "Create a graphical ad for an open source project" and didn't see that you said it was going to be on StackOverflow only. I was just so excited to make a Pidgin ad! I guess you could use it to chat with your dev team!

Comment: I would really love to see a Pidgin add for developers, could this be fixed?

Answer (score 17):

[OpenDS: LDAP services made easy http://www.opends.org/images/opends_ad.jpg](http://www.opends.org)

Comment: Why "mn" instead of "minutes"? There's plenty of space.

Comment: Installs and runs in less than 3 Minnesotas?

Comment: Don't just about any servers install in under 3 minutes now? It's the configuration and customization to your application that takes all the time.

Comment: @dlamblin You've clearly never installed Microsoft SQL Server :)

Comment: That image has some nasty compression artefacts.  Regenerate it as a gif/png?

Comment: @therefromhere: Yeah, besides JPEGs are not allowed as ad images.

Comment: @random - yes, I tested it scientifically. I started the install and began with `one Minnesota .. two Minessotas ...` it was done by the time I got to three. I spoke very, very slowly.

Comment: @Tim: the traditional state for that is `Mississippi`

Comment: @SamB - I know, I was being sardonic.

Answer (score 17):

[image: Open Source Hosting Control Panel]

Answer (score 17):

[Open, extensible, and neutral automation platform for .NET testing tools. http://www.gallio.org/images/GallioAdOnStackOverflow.png](http://www.gallio.org)

Comment: Looks like a toilet.

Comment: The Gallio Automation Platform is an open, extensible, and neutral system for .NET that provides a common object model, runtime services and tools (such as test runners) that may be leveraged by any number of test frameworks (MbUnit versions 2 and 3, MSTest, NBehave, NUnit, xUnit.Net, csUnit, and RSpec). Gallio provides tool support and integration with AutoCAD, CCNet, MSBuild, NAnt, NCover, Pex, Powershell, Resharper, TestDriven.Net, TypeMock, and Visual Studio Team System.

Comment: Needs fewer but sexier looking words.

Comment: Really looks like a toilet. Also the "column" is improperly drawn - its upper base is not parallel to the upper base - the ellips of the upper base is too compressed.

Answer (score 15):

[image: Watir, automated testing that doesn’t hurt. Looking for developers.]

Comment: +1, but a description (or at least a name) would be useful. Otherwise everyone is gonna get curious and click it (good tactic btw).

Comment: I have provided this text with the image: `Watir, automated testing that doesn’t hurt. Looking for developers.` I thought it will display as tool tip. Not sure what went wrong. :)

Comment: Added tool tip. Took a look how Rails did it.

Comment: Thanks to everybody that voted up, and to those that tried. :)

Comment: Added (really) the tool tip. =)

Comment: -1 because it doesn't say anything

Comment: There is tool tip text.

Comment: a) I see no tooltip here.  b) It should state what it's for without requiring the user to mouseover and wait for a tooltip to appear.

Comment: Tooltips are done with title="", not alt="".

Comment: Yeah, doesn't everybody know that tooltips are only for the extra bonus punchline?

Comment: Artwork is boring and drab.

Comment: My response on seeing that ad is "What is this ad for?"  This is not what you want in an ad where you're looking for people.  Maybe I'm just too old and jaded, but when I see obvious "faux mystery" ads I pass them over without a second glance because I hate the gimmickry.

Answer (score 13):

[image: RabbitVCS - Git on board]
<sub>(source: [rabbitvcs.org](http://wiki.rabbitvcs.org/wiki/_media/rvcsad.png))</sub>

Comment: RabbitVCS used to be known as NautilusSVN. It's basically a clone of TortoiseSVN for the GNOME desktop. It comprises a set of extensions for Subversion workflow in Nautilus, GEdit and Thunar. We're also working on getting the Git side of things up and running. It's written in Python (PyGTK for the UI).

Comment: +1 I hope this gets more votes!

Comment: Me too! We're a two person team at the moment, so we'd welcome any and all help :)

Comment: I just gave this the 6th vote to get it served. Nice clean ad :)

Answer (score 12):

**editorial: disallowed** -- while the joke is funny, not enough people would be "in" on it to understand why we have scantily-clad ladies in advertisements on the site.

[image: Write and compile jQuery in C#]

Comment: 2 downvotes, how could anyone dislike Evony?!

Comment: I hate Evony, but your take on their advertising is genius! :D

Comment: @Chris: Sorry, meant to click the up-arrow, but i got... distracted.

Comment: it is funny but a) it's hard to read and b) for those not in on the joke it's just an ad with cleavage which they'll probably email us to complain about. So -1 from me

Comment: I can see how you couldn't realistically be able to show it. I'll attempt a none-lawsuit version. The font is way too small I agree

Comment: I love the ad, but I don't like the project... what to do....

Comment: jeff already pimped evony on his blog, so you can't pimp it here either :p

Comment: @Chris: I could have lived my whole life and not seen the moob pic. Thank you for scarring me. (Also, those Evony ads have actually gotten **worse:** http://contexts.org/socimages/2009/07/14/evolution-of-evony-video-game-ads/)

Comment: I like the _joke_, but wouldn't actually want the ad served on the SO.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Programmer's Notepad - Help Wanted]
<sub>(source: [pnotepad.org](http://www.pnotepad.org/images/pnad1.png))</sub>

Comment: Yeah, I suck at making adverts, but I'm not bad at writing text editors :)

Comment: Very sexy ad IMO, +1 from me. =)

Comment: Yeah, it's the best of, well, this last page anyway ;-)

Comment: It's now off the last page :) Let's keep pushing it up. I don't want to be the only one to discover this in spite of the people spewing Notepad++ everywhere...

Answer (score 12):

[image: Hack, Make your own language, Become a Racketeer!]
<sub>(source: [barzilay.org](http://tmp.barzilay.org/racket-ad.png))</sub>

Comment: Great way to generate buzz, ambiguous add that points to a "coming soon" website. Not very informative but appealing to the sense of curiosity.

Comment: I should have explained that "coming soon" thing -- our project is a language that is currently called "PLT Scheme" (http://plt-scheme.org/) and we have been working for two months on renaming it to "Racket".  This moves includes a new domain name which is what this should point to -- but since we're not done with the new release we don't have the content up yet.  We're now busy with the new release, so the content will be there very soon, within 1-2 weeks at most.  (And coming up with a new language means that we're eager for contributions hence the ad idea...)

Comment: Upvoted for my favorite pl,but I can't believe this is actually happening!

Comment: kunjaan: Sure it is...  It's just around the corner now!

Answer (score 11):

[LiquiBase-Database Version Control http://liquibase.org/liquibasedotnet2.png](http://liquibase.org/dotnetport)

Comment: Removed the schema.  Does that seem less better?

Comment: "less better"?!

Comment: Leaking oil is a bad thing right now...

Answer (score 11):

[image: XAMPP - Apache, FTP, MySQL, PHP and Perl for Windows, Mac, Linux and Solaris]

Comment: Is that a penis?

Comment: And following the link, the girl on the page has a look on her face that says she's rather disappointed that it's bent.

Comment: Lol, xampp. Real gurus install apache themselves. DIE! (not enough rep to downvote, unfortunately)

Comment: @Flavius A: I've installed Apache *et all* many times before but XAMPP makes it not so boring. They have over half a million downloads per month, must mean something.

Comment: This is the easy to swallow pill that allows people to get hooked on a WAMP stack. Plus it can be run off a USB stick.

Comment: This is also the way allowing people not to learn anything about the environment they are, actually, programming. Why are there so many crappy PHP programmers? Go figure.

Comment: The apache setup you have running behind the scene has nothing to do with the quality of your code... note the drupal ad

Comment: You have a point @Flavius but if you expect everyone who wants to learn build web applications to learn how to set up Apache first, they'll be bored to death before even writing the first line of code. XAMPP is great.

Comment: why is there a big giant wang on stackoverflow?  BTW, I love XAMPP, hate the logo though

Comment: XAMPP is great, logo is better suited for a lower resolution I suspect. I saw exactly what everyone else sees.

Comment: You people need to stop watching so much porn! The logo resembles a bone or a rounded "X" way better than a half hard, half flaccid penis.

Comment: I thought it was a dog...

Comment: @Skilldrick: I bet you're into zoophilia then... xP I see a woman with big (kinda squared) breasts and with her legs wide open.

Comment: I understand it's supposed to be a creative *X* but it just looks like a blob instead.

Comment: @Alix Axel: Don't blame us for watching too much porn when you're the one posting phallic symbols!

Comment: im sorry but that is a wang. branding fail.

Comment: Phallic or not, WTF? What does this symbol have to do with PHP or Apache or anything else?

Comment: @Agnel: It's an `x`, where `x` is either [L(inux)/W(windows)/M(ax)] for a A(pache)M(ySQL)P(HP)P(erl) stack.

Comment: @Alix, There are so many other ways to depict an 'X' without being suggestive.

Answer (score 11):

[image: Help to improve WYMeditor]

Comment: FYI, it's a *semantic* text editor. Yes, the ad needs more information, and a catch phrase, like: "help make the content on the web sanely structured", or something like that, but more catchy.

Comment: absolutely love WymEditor but the ad could be way catchier :)

Comment: Maybe spell out WYSIWYM, with the WYM emphasized? or at least the M?

Comment: I understand you're a coder and you want to attract coders but the use of code in the ads is getting a little over-done. It's a `<p>` tag for crying out-loud...

Answer (score 11):

[Kohana needs Documentation! http://ep2up.com/uploads/1267708653.png](http://github.com/kohana/userguide)

Comment: Huh... This image kinda sucks...

Comment: Too bad, I did my best.

Comment: looks good to me

Comment: I wish I knew where to start with contributing, this would be a project I'd like to offer my programming time.

Comment: I like Kohana very much, so some constructive criticism. While the logo looks nice *in itself*, it looks nothing like the Kohana logo on the home page (www.kohanaphp.com, we *are* talking about the same project right?). There's 0% recognition effect this way. Then, it would be really nice to be led to a page that explains what the matter is: Why Kohana needs people to document it, where the project is at in terms of versions etc., what is already there, and a step-by-step guide on how to get started. In its current state, I don't think it's attracting too many developers.

Comment: @Pekka This is the new logo: http://v3.kohanaphp.com/. Most things are still under development, like the official site. I am depending on that. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 10):

[CppCMS Needs Your Help http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/ad-220-220.png](http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/wikipp/en/page/contrib)

Comment: I am highly interested on the topic, but the website really needs some work. Why does it highlight the coding style of the project, but does not tell anything about the project itself? The ad at least shows a little code fragment. Make the front page catch the user's attention, make him interested, make him desire to use the product and have him take the action of actually downloading and trying it out (marketing 101).

Comment: @Tronic, as you can see the link redirects to the "how to contribute" to project page -- because, according to policy these ads are rather ads that ask to help the project rather the project itself. So you only need to go to main page -- http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/wikipp/en/page/main to see what is all about.

Comment: The black text makes it a bit unreadable with that background.

Comment: What color would you suggest for text?

Comment: White in this case, I'd say.

Comment: I've tried but white looks even less readable over blue sky.

Comment: White or black, also make it bolder. Too thin to read well on my laptop.

Comment: This whole concept is just crazy. Web app? C++? What the heck?

Comment: @SamB Read this <http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/wikipp/en/page/rationale> and this <http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/wikipp/en/page/faq> before you say "Crazy"...

Comment: Use black text with white border?

Comment: The dark, grey-blue sky is dreary and depressing. Based on this ad alone, I'm not excited about CppCMS.

Comment: The extra time/energy/cost spent by debugging, bug reporting, yelling, smashing computers and getting new ones, visiting insane asylums, cleaning up after hackers smashing the stack, memory leaks etc, etc will certainly be more than whatever CO2 was saved by coding in C++...

Comment: @Nicolás why not white text with black border? more distinctive with bright bg

Comment: @Longpoke, smashing the stack? memory leaks? These problems have already been solved once and for all in the C++ world... RAII takes care of not only memory but *any* resource type...

Comment: @Agnel Kurian: and yet the programs, they still crash sometimes!

Comment: @SamB as java, python or any other language - crash

Comment: @SamB and @Longpoke, I just wrote some code today instantiating objects (3rd party objects... lot's of trigonometry and floating ponts) on stack and calling methods on them within an `if` block. These objects and methods are quite resource intensive. Using C++, I know that all resources are released once I exit the `if` without having to muck around with `finalize()` methods. I know this simply by having looked at the source code for the destructor. Which GC only language can give me such peace of mind? If I want a GC, I already have one: http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/. Thanks.

Comment: -1 Lets stop using C++ for everything because its insecure and old.(Its funny because i'm a C++ dev for a living) PHP's hiphop is an exception because your developing/debugging in a modern language.

Comment: @Artyom: Java is superior to C++ on the order of magnitudes in terms of security. A crash in C++ usually means someone can take over your computer. A crash in Java means perhaps a system partially fails. @Agnel: Orly? Then why do I get malware when I boot up Firefox (written in C++) and visit a few sites? GC is the only potential bad thing about high level languages, the tiny (and mostly mitigated) overhead of virtual lookup etc simply does not matter as its WCET is O(1). What does `finalize` have to do with anything? If I want determinism, I have it, RTjava, Ada..

Answer (score 9):

[image: Perl (and Python!) Template Toolkit]

Comment: Cool. What about it?

Comment: @macek:  What do you want to know?   Template Toolkit it arguably one of the most used opensource templating systems out there and used by some big companies.  Its a grandaddy of the template systems and as influenced many others of the years.  TT2 is currently available in Perl & Python.  And there is a complete TT3 rewrite which could always do with a hand or two: http://github.com/abw/Template-TT3

Comment: Dang True! For what it does TT is one of the open source greats. TT docs should be required reading for anyone who works with or builds any kind of string templating system.

Comment: I was giving you a hard time because it doesn't solicit programmer contribution. You're advertising a product.

Comment: @macek: I didn't realise u were giving me a hard time :)  TT is an opensource project like others on here and like them programmer contribution is their life blood.

Answer (score 9):

[Help build KDE http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/3187/kdelogoad.png](http://techbase.kde.org/Welcome_to_KDE_TechBase)

Comment: Needz moar details...

Comment: I like the logo

Comment: ImageShack seems to have deleted your image and [replaced it with an ad of their own.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263771) If you can reupload it, please do so; otherwise please consider deleting this answer.

Answer (score 8):

[image: N2 CMS]

Comment: I thought this was about contributing, not trying it out.

Comment: You'll probably want to try the product before before contributing. The checkins are very active, usually daily

Comment: upvote to 5 because I'm feeling nice :p

Comment: I can't figure out what license this is distributed on.

Comment: @Dave GNU Lesser Public

Comment: Web site is down!

Comment: @user130648: might want to go to your profile page and pull in the bio stuff from your SO (or wherever) profile ...

Answer (score 8):

[image: Incanter, Data Sorcery with Clojure]
<sub>(source: [incanter.org](http://incanter.org/images/incanter-so.png))</sub>

Comment: Thanks Shane! I like both of your rstats ads too, and will vote for them once I've got enough reputation :-)

Answer (score 8):

[image: All-in-one installers and virtual appliances for open source server software]
<sub>(source: [bitrock.com](http://bitrock.com/so-bitnami.png))</sub>

Comment: Nice icons, ad, and product:)

Answer (score 7):

[image: NPOI for your Excel needs]

Comment: Can someone with graphic talent give this image some love?

Comment: I can't tell what NPOI does.

Comment: @Mauricio - NPOI needs someone with graphic talent to give it some love! :) But in the meantime, NPOI is used to read/write Excel .xls files in Microsoft .NET Framework.

Comment: Is that a coffee cup? On a .NET ad?

Comment: is this supposed to be npoiX? where the X is a paper and gumball grinder? *"I'll take a small paper gumball macchiato, please"*

Comment: I used this in my project. It's good stuff.

Answer (score 6):

[bbsharp - a DOM parsing BBCode implementation written in C# - help us develop it! http://anyhub.net/file/so_ad.png](http://github.com/charliesome/bbsharp)

Comment: I see no image.

Comment: Looks clean and fresh.

Answer (score 6):

[image: all over the manual]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Find Time For TimeFinder!]

Comment: Find Time For TimeFinder and join the Team!

Comment: Looks cool but IMHO it's too abstract

Comment: What do you think should be improved? I think this ad is targeted to developers and they will understand, won't they?
May I should put the 'Find Time For TimeFinder' slogan directly under the images?

Comment: I wouldn't count on it. At least add a tagline or brief description or something below the equation stuff--you've got plenty of room.

Answer (score 5):

[Go to the so++ homepage! http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/sopp_ad.png](http://launchpad.net/sopp)

Comment: Okay, basically this is a C++ wrapper for the StackOverflow/ServerFault/SuperUser/Meta/StackApps API. It has come a long way and supports the vast majority of API calls.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Circumflex — lightweight Web framework and ORM for Scala]
<sub>(source: [circumflex.ru](http://circumflex.ru/img/banner.png))</sub>

Comment: Hrmm. Where's the ad?

Comment: the script text is barely legible.

Comment: Yeap. They usually call it branding.

Answer (score 4):

[image: PDL - the Perl Data Language | Number crunching capabilities for Perl]

Comment: It shows "This photo is currently unavailable" to me.

Comment: @KennyTM - I thought it was SO cacheing the image that caused that.. but I have now noticed extra cruft on end of the image URL :(   Have fixed now.

Comment: PDL rocks. While the logo isn't really elegant, it's showing the library's roots in astronomy nicely.

Comment: I'm probably not the first to say programmers aren't designers for a reason...

Comment: @macek:  Well at least it got it 15 mins of fame - http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/stackoverflow_business_funding.php

Comment: ouch, can you even see the logo if you're colour blind?

Comment: Needs more Unicorns! - btw, what is PDL? should the image not contain some info about what it is?

Comment: Its an old logo which has recently been updated along with the website.  The logo still doesn't describe what it is but I did add it to the ALT element here (which only shows when ad is used though!).  PS.  PDL is for Perl Data Language.  More at website and also how to contribute here: http://pdl.perl.org/?page=mailing-lists

Answer (score 4):

[image: Contribute to the world's leading open source NAC!]

Comment: PacketFence is an amazing open source project. I've met some of the people behind it and I know that they really deserve to get some more attention / love.

Comment: The text is a bit hard to read; letters too vertically stretched. You should consider another font.

Comment: Includes checklist? Check.

Answer (score 4):

[image: The sky is the limit!]

Comment: Wing Beats is an internal little language (DSL) for creating XHTML. It is based on F# and includes an ASP.NET MVC view engine, but can also be used solely for it's capability of creating XHTML.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Kopal - Distributed Social Networking.]

Comment: I think this deserves a lot more attention.

Comment: "Help us get better"? "Help us become better"? The poor grammar, it burns us.

Comment: "I'm not a native English speaker and learning only by experiences. Also I'm still not convinced that _help us getting better_ is incorrect grammatically. I might change my views and the ad picture if get more comments about it." - Author.

Comment: Just a humble request - 

If you find the advertisement grammatically incorrect, please respond by a comment and **not** by a negative vote.

You're also welcome to suggest a better statement.

Comment: @mllerustad: I guess they really do need help!

Comment: +1, but how does this differ from Diaspora (http://www.joindiaspora.com/)?

Comment: Zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

Comment: Yes, getting better is wrong..

Comment: @Alix Axel - Well, they have 200,000 USD and media coverage to boot with.

Comment: @user140810 - For start, you can help with English documentations. :)

Comment: [EDIT] Reverted back to previous image.

Answer (score 3):

[image: PHP TestFest]

Answer (score 3):

[Open Source Management Solution - ERP http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/254/thumbs/1931078746_b.jpg](http://openerp.com)

Answer (score 3):

[image: Contribute to OpenLieroX]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://openlierox.sourceforge.net/olxcontribute.png))</sub>

Comment: My god, I loved liero. Albert, the ad could still use a little work, though.

Comment: As said in another post, "Liero is a game that is totally worth checking out. That said, this ad doesn't do it a lot of justice." (macek). Just a digging worm cannot call more programmers and players. Put 1 more worm and more 2 players with another skin, more weapons shotting and some explosion on a better level. The text would be in a more aggressive font; the text could be and like that: "OpenLieroX: a game with a lot of explosions for worms and brains". You can add piece of code as watermark in some picture part - like little lua commands.

Answer (score 2):

[image: ZNC: The best IRC bouncer, now available for Microsoft Windows!]

Comment: I like the sentiment and the project seems cool but the ad needs to be less.. obnoxious :p

Comment: To bounce less?

Comment: You can't use the Microsoft Windows logo, even if you do 'shop out the (R) mark.

Comment: also, why use the MS Windows logo, if doesnt even runs in windows out of the box!

Comment: @Fladur ..because the linked-to project is about a Windows port? "[...] to bring the best IRC bouncer out there to Windows as well"

Comment: @unknown: You can if it's about windows. There are other examples in this thread.

Comment: Good idea for an ad; but I suggest smaller font for 'suck'... maybe the size of 'less'. Either way, 'suck less' should be same size imho

Comment: The ad sucks, too.

Answer (score 1):

[Ruby on Rails http://img443.imageshack.us/img443/6941/rorg.png](http://rubyonrails.org/)

Comment: * Until you try to upgrade from one point version to the next and find that one small thing has changed and your code no longer works

Comment: -1, already a RoR ad here

Comment: Ad is for product, not asking for help!

Comment: ImageShack seems to have deleted your image and [replaced it with an ad of their own.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263771) If you can reupload it, please do so; otherwise please consider deleting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: A toolkit for building scalable, community-oriented web applications.]

Comment: For starters, that logo doesn't fulfill the size requirements.

Comment: If you have a better image, please say you do, post the URL in the comments and someone with enough rep will fix up.

Comment: This has to be one of the worst mascots ever but here is a better image: http://fisheye.openacs.org/browse/~raw,r=1.1/OpenACS/openacs.org-dev/www/templates/openacs_logo_large.gif

Comment: How about a description of what OpenACS does?

Comment: @Alix Axel, that is a "better" image? :)

Comment: @macek: At least it has a higher level of detail. =)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Join the team and enhance the fun]

Comment: As requested, a new version that hopefully clarifies what Performous is.

Comment: First ad I see that mentions an IRC channel. I think it's a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

[Working quick start ASP.NET MVC on mono http://shaml.sztupy.hu/images/shamlad.png](http://code.google.com/p/shaml-architecture/)

Comment: pictures mashed with <insert graphic> words. italics. S#aml.

Comment: really helpful. Care to explain more?

Comment: The formatting is just sloppy. Why is *everything* italic? Define the elements: you have 1) a logo, 2) big ad text, 3) ad body text, 4) mono logo. They're all scattered about the page. This ad simply directs my eyes to look somewhere else rather than actually continue reading to find out what it's about.

Answer (score -2):

[JStock - Free Stock Market Software http://sites.google.com/site/yanchengcheok/Home/stackoverflow1.png](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/jstock/index.php?title=Main_Page)

Comment: Tells me nothing!

Answer (score -13):

[I, THE WHITE HOUSE USE DRUPAL; read more... http://pendashteh.ir/images/drupal.png](http://drupal.org)

Comment: all drupalists'! vote to take off over the previous shaming ad of drupal.

Comment: Respectfully, you may wish to re-consider your approach if you are trying to make a more 'favorable' impression. How does this ad help to counteract the message of the previous ad? If anything, it seems to perfectly *reinforce* the point. 

Even if people can decipher your point about the White House, U.S. Government agencies are *notorious* for deploying sloppy, bloated, inelegant code that no one wants to acknowledge, let alone maintain. Ask anybody with knowledge on this subject.

Comment: here is for advertise a project not attracting developers. i don't know what was the aim of the previous ad. i just want to cover it's bad aspects on visitrs.

Comment: The Ad requirements say: "It must be an advertisement soliciting the participation and contribution of programmers writing actual source code. This is not intended as a general purpose ad for consumer products which just happen to be open source."

Comment: yes, you right. but most of ads above have nothing to do with developers. they are just ad.

Comment: Um, the ad means nothing to me...

Comment: VERTICAL text is very easy to read with my top and bottom eyes.

Comment: I wish I could vote this down again.

Comment: I like the semicolon, But I'd change the rest of the image.

Comment: So what do they use and why do I need it? I have no clue what this ad is advertising from the look of it.