# My icon show 75% with just one question asked

Tags: support, accept-rate, information-display, user-information

The question says it all... I see it says 75% for me [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31913/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2010/31955#31955), why.  I only have one question and I selected an answer.

Comment: This is a good question - I don't think I've seen this explained anywhere. @balpha is correct.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've read that somewhere, but I don't recall when or where.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That number has nothing to do with your accept rate (which would only appear on your questions, not your answers). This number says that with 75%, most of the content (75%, specifically) of this community wiki answer comes from you.

Comment: Ah... the percent of a wiki comment authored.
Got it.  Thanks!