# running open source ads on 3rd party websites

Tags: feature-request, advertising, open-source

As commented by @dlamblin on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31913/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2010) I would also be interested by the ads system of stackoverflow to be reusable on other websites.

Would it be possible or a similar system does exist already?

Answer (score 2):

This is more than possible.

I have created a tool called [StackAd](https://stackapps.com/questions/741/stackad-an-easy-way-to-display-open-source-ads-on-your-site-blog) for exactly this purpose. Follow the easy instructions on [this](http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/stackad/) page to embed the ads on your blog.

Comment: +1 I really admire your 'extra mile' scripts and ideas...where is your diamond?

Comment: @david: I'm only a mod. on StackApps :)