# Open source project ad feed?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, advertising, flair

SO runs ads for open source projects, for free, based on community voting :

[Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 1H 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31913/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2010)

Is there an official/supported way that an enthusiastic user could tap in and serve these ads on their own site/blog.  Now my site gets <0 traffic.  But many SO users run pretty popular side sites and blogs.  What if we could hit some URL and get a random open source project ad for our own sites, like flair.  These ads are up voted and "vetted" by meta users so if you are an avid user and trust the community you know the content is worthwhile.

This could exponentially increase the exposure for these projects.  Links could bring people back to the meta question to vote and/or to stack overflow to provide some, albeit minimal, publicity for SO as well.  Thoughts?

Apologize if this is a dupe/already exists.

Comment: This sounds like a really good idea! I would run them on my site too

Comment: looks like this was brought up previously, though maybe no explained as thoroughly : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37429/running-open-source-ads-on-3rd-party-websites

Answer (score 4):

I would like to know how many people would actually do this.

Up-vote **this** post (made wiki) **if you have a website** *and* you would be interested in running [Free Vote-Based Advertising for Open Source Projects](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/).

Comment: Why not just upvote the question? Isn't that how we typically comment on feature-requests on MSO? Esp. with http://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=requests

Comment: @waiwai933 - Because up-voting the question means only that you like the idea. **Not** that you would (or could) run ads.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackapps.com/questions/741/stackad-an-easy-way-to-display-open-source-ads-on-your-site-blog) the tool you're looking for?