# Attention before closing a question as exact duplicate

Tags: discussion

At first see the questions below:

> - [Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 1H 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31913/)
> - [Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 2H 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53346/)

Here first question([Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 1H 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31913/)) is closed as exact duplicate of the second question ([Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 2H 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53346/)). All contents of the first question is exactly copied to the second.

Now see the time of posting of both questions

> - [Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 1H 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31913/) : Dec 4 2009 at 22:45
> - [Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 2H 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53346/) : Jun 11 2010 at 15:50

So actual duplicate question will be second one ([Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 2H 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53346/)). Then why first question is closed. I think it is very essential to view the time of posting while someone closing a question.

Comment: Notice: In this case asker of the second question closed the first one.

Comment: This is a very special question, as it serves as the source for the Open Source advertising rotation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the newer question has better content than the older question, closing the older question is a good idea.

<sub>*(Note, your example is a very special case)*</sub>

[Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61611/attention-before-closing-a-question-as-exact-duplicate/61616#61616) also makes a good point that chronology on Stack Overflow is far less important than on your run-of-the-mill forum.

Comment: I think closing the first question is not a good idea. Author of the second question can leave a comment to see the send question for better content.

Comment: @chan, there is no harm in closing the first question.  The first question will contain a link to the second.  And, the second question, which already had better content, will remain open.

Comment: But the word "as exact duplicate" is very bad here.

Comment: @chan, I guess I do not see the harm.

Answer (score 1):

> I think it is very essential to view the time of posting while someone closing a question.

Not necessarily... Don't get too hung up on chronology - this isn't a forum; any post can be revised at any time.

*Usually*, the older question will be a better choice as the target for links because it will have the most refined answers, the most editing, and *it will have more links to it already*... But this isn't *always* the case; it may be that an earlier question was poorly asked or failed to garner much attention for some other reason, and so it makes sense to direct readers to the newer, better-phrased or better-answered question.

If *both* questions have good answers, you can request that a moderator merge them: this will consolidate all answers on one, leaving the other a stub that does nothing but direct readers to the more active question.

And [as the jjnguy notes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61611/attention-before-closing-a-question-as-exact-duplicate/61612#61612), the example you cite isn't normal *at all*.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, The person who did that must have been some kind of Über-genius or something; such brilliant and innovative use of the tools at hand.

The original question was to provide an aggregate of answers for the contest. The contest was over so the questions was **closed**. The terms of the second contest were an exact duplicate of the first so the question was **closed as an exact duplicate**. Anyone who searches and finds the first questions is conveniently pointed to the open, relevant content of the second question!

Considering the brilliance of it all brings just a bit of a tear to my eye.