# Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 1H 2011

Tags: discussion, open-source-advertising, crowdsourcing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 2H 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93312/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2011)

It's time once again to support your favorite open source project through our Free Vote-Based Advertising for Open Source Projects. We are clearing the leader boards to start the first half of 2011 anew.

Here is your chance to create a [Free Vote-Based Advertisement for an Open Source Project](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/). Create a graphical ad for an open source programming project and post it as an answer to this question (in the right format), and it will feed live remnant ads on Stack Overflow.

### Ad Requirements

It must be an advertisement **soliciting the participation and contribution of programmers writing actual source code**. This is not intended as a general purpose ad for consumer products which just happen to be open source. It's for finding programmers who will help contribute code or other programmery things (documentation, code review, bug fixes, etc.).

Your ad should be an original creation which has not previously appeared on Stack Overflow. Please do not resubmit entries that have appeared as ads on Stack Overflow in previous periods.

In order to work, the answers you post to this question **must** conform to the following rules.

### Answer Template

```
[![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]
    
  [1]: http://image-url
  [2]: http://clickthrough-url
```

Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to add any commentary, keep it in the comments.

### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 pixels by 250 pixels**
- Can be hosted anywhere (tinypic, twitpic, your blog); we will mirror the image locally when we serve it.
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

The output, which ultimately will be served in an ad slot on Stack Overflow, can be previewed by clicking through to this URL:

http://rads.stackoverflow.com/ossads/220x250

### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be served up by that URL and shown on Stack Overflow. You can see all the ads that currently make the threshold and meet our criteria on this page:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/74983

You can also view the ads that meet the threshold using [George Edison](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/142114/george-edison)'s [StackAd Scroller](http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/stackad/fancy.html)

Comment: Is there a license requirement for the ads? Can we assume the images are under the same CC license as the rest of the SO content? (I'm asking for reusability in other FLOSS ad networks.)

Comment: @mario is that FLOSS as in TWIT?

Comment: I figured you were. FLOSS is the name of a podcast on the This Week In Tech network, check out http://twit.tv/floss

Comment: @mario: As the original owner of the material (Licensor), you are allowed to post your ad on *other* networks WITHOUT attribution (i.e. "Licensor reserves the right to release the Work under different license terms...",  Section 7(b) http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/legalcode). But that only applies to *you*. Everyone else would have to provide attribution if they re-posted your ad. And yes, *all* user-contributed content is licensed under CC BY-SA for reuse (with attribution), including the ads.

Comment: I noticed the format for the ad uses the alt text space for the title text. Shouldn't we use the *title* text for the erm... title text? Some browsers do not show the alt text when you mouseover the image.

Comment: Indeed, the template is wrong. In sane browsers, the `alt` text is NOT shown on mouse over. And even when shown by non-compliant browsers, the `alt` should be describing what is missing, not some tag line. So maybe it should be labeled *"The text used on browsers that don't support images"* (like by readers used by visually impaired). If a mouse over is wanted too, then **besides** the `alt` attribute, the `title` should be specified as well, after the image or link URL. Like: `[1]: http://image-url "Tagline to show on mouseover"`

Comment: @Rebecca: Can you please clarify something as there seems to be a bit of confusion: some of the ads were posted in the previous threads, but never got the 6-vote threshold and therefore were never shown. It was understood last time that the ads that didn't make the cut were allowed to be reposted the next time around. Could we please have some clarification?

Comment: @mario: See [this](http://stackapps.com/questions/741/stackad-an-easy-way-to-display-open-source-ads-on-your-site-blog) tool for an easy way to do that.

Comment: **Note:** As with previous [iterations](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53346/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2010-closed#comment-125255) of this program, entries that have appeared as ads in previous periods are not eligible; however, previous entries that did **not** meet the minimum score threshold can be resubmitted.

Comment: Interested in election integrity?  Got design skills?  The [ElectionAudits project (audit elections with good statistical confidence)](https://launchpad.net/electionaudits) needs some better icons/CSS/web design.  Which is to say that, uh, I'm not the one to do a nice snazzy ad for it.  Anyone willing to take a cut at it?  Thanks :)

Comment: http://rads.stackoverflow.com/ossads/all => this link is broken.

Comment: Really once more. +1 for the great idea!

Comment: Although I'm using the image button to upload, I stackoverflow does not take my proposal. It keeps saying: "Community ads must have an image hosted at imgur.com - use the image button to upload". What's the problem with that?

Answer (score 56):

[image: SEScripts - Help us help you help us all!]

Comment: Doesn't that violate some serious copyrights?

Comment: @Constantin Please specifiy which copyrights you are referring to?

Comment: @Diago: Sorry, I was thinking it would be already obviously enough. I referring to: http://www.nintendo.com/corp/legal.jsp#copyrights

Comment: Copyrights and trademarks. The likeness of mario would be protected by trademark as well.

Comment: Wouldn't this only violate copyright only if it actually copies graphics/words rather than just the ideas?  You can't copyright all instances of "a castle next to a flag on a pole".  I don't know how trademarks apply in this case.  (Ah, I see the original version did copy Mario's image.)

Comment: @FredNurk: This uses the ground texture straight from Super Mario World: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_C6b7IUiHh4&t=7s

Comment: @R.Bemrose: Then that graphic should be replaced as well.

Comment: Aren't you allowed to use ideas artistically/humorously, even if they're trademarked? Also, no money is being made off of this, since it's an open source project. I don't think there's any need to change it further unless Nintendo actually threatens legal action.
Don't let the big, scary companies bully you!

Answer (score 40):

[image: RoboGuice - The #1 Dependency Injection framework for Android]

Comment: Nice framework, help a lot in android dev!

Comment: The logo looks so cool!

Comment: Great for Android application development.

Comment: Excellent for saving time not having to wire everything manually

Comment: Anyone know why the hover text isn't working on this one?  Format seems identical to StackExchangeScripts, which has a working hover text

Answer (score 34):

[image: Hackers wanted!]

Comment: +1 - Unity needs all the programmers it can get :P

Comment: Text positioning and a background similar to [this](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jonobacon/5104942057/) would look good here.

Comment: [A variation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74983/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2011/77435#77435).

Comment: It'll never be as good as Gnome. The only thing it's good for is drawing serious people away from Ubuntu (including myself).

Comment: Love the new look!

Answer (score 33):

[image: Kod - Programmers' Editor for OS X]

Comment: I feel it's missing a description inside the image :(

Comment: @Macarse: it confirms to the template (alt attribute, no title).

Comment: Description is completely drown by the rest, difficult to read

Comment: I agree with CharlesB, I think the text could be made a bit more legible.  I like it!

Answer (score 32):

[image: NuGet it]

Answer (score 30):

[image: Tux4Kids - Educational Software Alternatives]

Comment: Tux4Kids develops educational software (videogames) for kids, with the goal of combining fun and learning into an irresistable package. We've just finished a grand overhaul through the Google Code-in programme and are looking for developers and graphic artists to help out with further development.

Answer (score 30):

[image: Sage - Python based cutting edge mathematics]

Comment: should "open source" appear somewhere on the ad, or does it go without saying?

Comment: I wonder if this is visible somehow in the "math" Stack Exchange - site?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think so.  As far as I can tell it's only Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 28):

[image: boost is a collection of high quality libraries developed for the twenty first century!]

Comment: My apology in advance for the naive design :)

Comment: There is only one problem with this Ad. Currently there are much more users willing to contribute to Boost and too few developers who actually want to be a review manager. So contributing is veeeery hard.

Comment: As an ad, it would be more effective if it told you what Boost is.

Comment: @lala I might change the design a bit to add a simple description. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: @AraK Just as a tip for you to take or leave: Tell us what it solves.  For example, increase_c++_productivity(); instead of just become_booster();

Comment: This image is 220x200 pixels. It has to be be 220x220.

Comment: When I first saw this, I didn't notice the sideways C. I read it as boost++ and thought it was some kind of enhancement to boost.

Answer (score 27):

[image: Help us build a better Python, in Python.]

Comment: I wouldn't mind if someone made a pretty version of this ;)

Answer (score 22):

[image: Our motivation is to bring the element of human context awareness to computer systems, paving the way for more user friendly and easier to use software.]

Comment: Using Zeitgeist you can keep a log of all the files you opened with exact times, create statistics, learn your workflow and make yourself more efficient. Zeitgeist does not log only files but any activity or event like receiving calls, dropping calls, starting a  track in your favorite media player. The possibilities are immense. The sky is the limit.

Comment: and its open source

Answer (score 22):

[Like Firebug for ASP.NET http://getglimpse.com/content/GlimpseStackAd.png](http://getglimpse.com)

Answer (score 15):

[CppCMS Needs Your Help http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/ad-2011a.png](http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/wikipp/en/page/contrib)

Comment: +1 Nice project, excellent support, and friendlier for the planet. Thanks!

Comment: tempted to give a -1 because of Comic Sans.

Comment: @Agos - what is the problem with Comic Sans - it looks fine in this context?

Comment: @Art COMIC SANS!  Slowly I turned... Step by step... Inch by inch...

Comment: Comic Sans was a fine font when originally created. Now it's everywhere and speaks "amateur." Still I'm upvoting this -- once upon a time I wrote a small CMS in C. Fun it was not, young Skywalker, but I have fond memories of its performance.

Comment: @Leonardo The problem in writing any kind of web application in C++ (and in C) is lack of good tools. C++ gives many goodies making programming fast and easy while CppCMS provides good web-development tools.

Comment: @Artyom Given that the context is an advertisement that will be served hundreds of thousands of time on a site for professionals, I don't think Comic Sans is 'fine'.

Comment: @Agos @Will Please all "Comic Sans" Down voters I've updated the font

Comment: @Art I didn't actually downvote you, don't worry

Answer (score 15):

[image: Spruce - a nice looking TFS web front end]

Comment: No votes last time :( TFS isn't very fashionable though :P. Screenshots: http://goo.gl/1vNuq

Comment: It's MVC3 now and looks a bit nicer: http://sprucetfs.wordpress.com/2011/05/15/three-months-later/

Answer (score 14):

[image: FluxBB - fast, light user-friendly PHP forum system]

Comment: @Yi Jiang: What about that link? It was a forum post created entirely for that purpose. I guess it's fine this way, though.

Comment: The previous link you posted was broken

Comment: Ah no, it wasn't. But it just appeared to me that the topic was in a member-only forum :P Thanks for finding.

Comment: Fluxbb for the win.

Answer (score 14):

[image: AnkiDroid]

Comment: Helps students/everyone memorize languages or anything that you could learn with paper flashcards. UI=Android, database=SQLite, sync with PC=REST. Efficient collaboration with Git. We welcome everyone and share privileges very quickly. Very open development processes, everything is public.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to vote this up, but AnkiDroid is a piece of open source software that I use everyday.

Comment: Is this supermemo based?

Comment: Chris S: The spaced repetition system is based on an older version of the SuperMemo algorithm called SM2. Subsequent versions of SuperMemo have managed to squeeze out a little more learning efficiency, but they come at the cost of greatly increased complexity, and they are more susceptible to scheduling errors in real-world use. We want to stay 100% compatible with "Anki", the desktop PC version, which is using this algorithm. Thanks for your interest!

Answer (score 13):

[image: Spark - A lightweight yet powerful JavaScript library.]

Comment: Before you ask, this did not get enough votes last time either.

Comment: The image links to the repository, but to get a bit of background on the library you could take a look at the documentation. http://sparkjs.co.uk/documentation

Comment: Nice font choices :)

Comment: Love the fonts too! :)

Comment: Thanks :] you would not believe the size of this font library! I should really redo the image though, make it a bit more interesting...

Comment: Hate the fonts.  Script isn't good for an ad.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I am about to upload a new version anyway.

Comment: I have written a JSON API for the docs now and implemented it in this chrome extension, head over to the docs for more info - http://bit.ly/dIXTtx

Comment: @Wolfy87: Looks cool! Do you have a demo page?

Comment: I did for an old version, I can set up a jsFiddle today demonstrating every function. I will link it later. Thanks for taking an interest!

Comment: @George Edison: Here is a page of examples, some functions are not used there but they are self explanatory ones. http://jsfiddle.net/Wolfy87/A7XXD/14/

Comment: @Wolfy87: Cool! +1

Comment: I am writing a document right now which goes into a lot more detail than the documentation does.

Comment: Just hit v2.0.0.

Comment: Speed testing against Mootools and jQuery, Spark wins 9.5/10! jQuery beats it on setting events by a tiny margin: http://tumblr.com/xxh1gw21ds

Answer (score 13):

[image: The Mylyn connector for Mantis allows you to manage your Mantis tasks straight from Eclipse]

Comment: Do you have a version in a lossless format (ie. png)? The jpeg compression artefacts are clearly visible here.

Comment: @Yi Jiang: no, unfortunately the MantisBT logo is available only in raster format.

Comment: You're confusing raster vs. vector with lossy vs lossless here - raster formats like png can also be lossless. The jpeg compression is too high here, so you see significant artefacts around the text. Oh, and I forgot to add, this advertisement is slightly too small to meet the requirements. It should be possible to process away some of the artefacts, but you'll also need to scale it up to 220x220, as stated in the question above.

Comment: @Yi Jiang - thanks for pointing those issues out. Fixed.

Answer (score 12):

[image: TwistLoad Download Manager]

Comment: lol, awesome slogan

Comment: I don't have the download blues, but I have the upload blues: I'm looking for a user-friendly upload system to upload *large* files onto a server.

Comment: @augustin: That's a feature planned for the future.

Comment: Call me confused, but is this an ad for me to download and use the application or to become and active coder on it? It clicked through to the project main page without any usable binaries so I was left confused and disappointed. Maybe the ad should go to some kind of landing page helping me to understand what you want me to do after clicking the ad.

Comment: @Frazell: Sorry... the ad is for someone to contribute to the project. There are no pre-built binaries on the Launchpad project page. To check out the code, visit https://code.launchpad.net/~george-edison55/twistload/trunk

Comment: Not bluish enough. Make the "blues" blue text. :)

Comment: @augustin What about https://www.wetransfer.com/ ?

Comment: @GnomeSlice thanks but no. I need a software solution / API that I can *integrate into my own CMS* to upload large files to *my* server.

Comment: @George - The link is pointing at the right place according to the guidelines, but this does look like an ad inviting the user to download and use the application.  Putting "Open Source" or "Developers Wanted" somewhere on the ad would be appropriate.

Comment: @reem: Hmmm... I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 10):

[image: 7Basic Compiler]

Comment: 7Basic is an attempt to create a BASIC-like language and compiler capable of generating 32 bit ELF and Win32 PE executable files. It has progressed well so far - it currently generates NASM x86 assembly code. The language currently has 3 types: `INTEGER`, `STRING`, & `FLOAT` (an IEEE 754 float internally). Currently supported constructs: variable assignments, basic arithmetic operations (addition, subtraction, etc...), logic operators (>, <, ==, etc...), and basic control statements (IF...THEN and WHILE).

Comment: One area for improvement for those interested: the assembly code generated is **SLOW** due to the nature of the assembly generating code. In fact, I tested a 7Basic snippet against an equivalent C program and the performance ratio was 80:1!

Answer (score 10):

[image: FogBugzpp - A C++ wrapper for the FogBugz XML API]

Comment: I have been looking for a wrapper similar to the great C#/.NET wrappers for FogBugz - but alas, not found one.  The primary reason for building this was to submit crash dumps to fogbugz with file attachments.  The BugzScout tool won't support file attachments and the email interface is not reliable on all client machines and I want to have "Scout" functionality.  Initial implementation is limited - only creates a simple case.

Comment: and a down-vote without a comment...! That's not cool (+1 for the lost vote)

Comment: For those who are curious about what I might like in an ad/graphics - nothing special - anything that strikes your fancy.  I don't see trademarks for FogBugz or the kiwi for tha matter - though i might ask Fog Creek about it if they would mind at all to add that as part of the theme.  C++ and something that evokes FogBuzg is all it takes.  And I do appreciate that the graphic is horrible.  I will withdraw the submission if I don't find a suitable graphic - it would not be appropriate - I know the team at SO has spent a lot ot time and energy on making the site look good.  thanks

Comment: And yes, Yi, it does look really bad.  You don't have to be polite about it.  :-)

Comment: You have Fog Creek's permission to use our logo and name in advertising this project.

Comment: tim: I hope you don't mind; I tried my hand out at making an ad for you. Revert it if you don't like it.

Answer (score 10):

[image: A simple and intuitive approach to interface your database with Java: jOOQ is Java Object Oriented Querying. jOOQ brings the relational world to Java without covering up its origins. jOOQ is relational. And object oriented. Just in a different way.]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://jooq.sourceforge.net/logo/stackoverflow.png))</sub>

Comment: This looks out of focus...?

Comment: You mean, literally? I drew it with a pen...

Answer (score 8):

[image: JetServer]

Comment: JetServer itself is the root process that manages communication with the other JetServer applications. (Currently JetFTP, JetHTTP, and JetDNS.)

Answer (score 8):

[image: CRest - RESTful service Java integration made easy]
<sub>(source: [codegist.org](http://crest.codegist.org/images/crest-ad-20110126.png))</sub>

Answer (score 8):

[image: Contribute to the world's leading open source NAC!]
<sub>(source: [packetfence.org](http://www.packetfence.org/pf-stackoverflow.png))</sub>

Comment: That font is pretty narrow...

Answer (score 8):

[image: One Click Orgs: A pioneering, free web app for groups to form a legal association and govern it through member votes. Coded in Rails 3.]
<sub>(source: [oneclickorgs.com](http://www.oneclickorgs.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/oneclickorgs.stackoverflow.20110208.png))</sub>

Comment: +1 Maybe "Web service" is ambiguous? It is a web interface for humans, not WSDL-like, as far as I know?

Comment: That's a good point, thanks! We've updated the wording on the ad.

Comment: Seems interesting, but clicking the ad just takes you to a git repository. I guess that's okay on StackOverflow.com, but if the ad is posted anywhere else people will expect to see an actual web site.

Comment: Yup, we are only using this ad on Stack Overflow -- it's specifically designed for programmers!

Answer (score 7):

[image: Roadkill .NET Wiki engine]

Comment: It's...kind of morbid...

Comment: @GnomeSlice No chickens were hurt in the making of this advert

Comment: +1, but I would suggest a more stomach friendly picture :)

Comment: @Zsub thanks for the vote, I'm not sure I can make anything pleasant based on the idea of a roadkill

Comment: What's the association with road kill? Because you're so hyper fast in creating web pages, that there might be casualties?

Comment: @Lukas I couldn't think of a name and have this sign in my kitchen: http://www.taverntoys.com/zencart_138/images/road%20kill.jpg. I'm starting to think it's probably not going to help the software spread with that name

Comment: @Chris, that's an awesome sign in your kitchen! Well the name's not necessarily bad, I just guess people are looking for a reason why you chose it. So it's enough for you to come up with any reason. You may use my suggestion with the casualties :-)