# Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 2H 2011

Tags: discussion, open-source-advertising, crowdsourcing, community-ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 1H 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114442/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2012)

It's time once again to support your favorite open source project through our Free Vote-Based Advertising for Open Source Projects. We are clearing the leader boards to start the second half of 2011 anew.

Here is your chance to create a [Free Vote-Based Advertisement for an Open Source Project](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/). Create a graphical ad for an open source programming project and post it as an answer to this question (in the right format), and it will feed live remnant ads on Stack Overflow.

### Ad Requirements

It must be an advertisement **soliciting the participation and contribution of programmers writing actual source code**. This is not intended as a general purpose ad for consumer products which just happen to be open source. It's for finding programmers who will help contribute code or other programmery things (documentation, code review, bug fixes, etc.).

Your ad should be an original creation which has not previously appeared on Stack Overflow. Please do not resubmit entries that have appeared as ads on Stack Overflow in previous periods.

In order to work, the answers you post to this question **must** conform to the following rules.

### Answer Template

```
[![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]
    
  [1]: http://image-url
  [2]: http://clickthrough-url
```

Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to add any commentary, keep it in the comments.

### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 pixels by 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

The output, which ultimately will be served in an ad slot on Stack Overflow, can be previewed by clicking through to this URL:

http://rads.stackoverflow.com/ossads/220x250

### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be served up by that URL and shown on Stack Overflow. You can see all the ads that currently make the threshold and meet our criteria on this page:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/93312

**Note:** *As with previous [iterations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53346/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2010-closed#comment-125255) of this program, entries that have appeared as ads in previous periods are not eligible; however, previous entries that did **not** meet the minimum score threshold can be resubmitted.*

Comment: I wrote up what I think the ads should do differently here: [Open Source ads need a more specific focus](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94836)

Comment: Hi, I am new to this Meta site of SO, therefore I have only 1 point for registration. For this reason I cannot add "an answer" below which constains an image. What should I do?

Comment: @Eye: Earn +200 reputation on one of your associated sites and you will get a 100 reputation bonus here.

Answer (score 27):

[image: Error Logging Modules and Handlers for ASP.NET!]

Comment: I get bennies from drawing narwhals.

Comment: @Won And you do it so *splendidly!*

Comment: Doesn't say anything about the project, this ad would simply confuse me and I'd ignore it

Comment: Except you didn't ignore it--you had to comment on it.  Advertising isn't always about informing the viewer, it sometimes is about grabbing their attention and sticking in their minds.

Comment: For the record, I just found out about this because narwhals are awesome, so the ad got my attention. Probably the first SO ad I've ever clicked on...

Comment: Gnarly has a normal belly here. What *has* he been doing between this, and that recent picture?

Comment: @Pekka'sseriousaccount: I cannot bring myself to answer this.

Comment: Cute narwhal -- and congrats on the first out-of-network advertisement I've clicked on. :)

Comment: It got my attention. After that I noticed it was about ELMAH, so I clicked because I like ELMAH. If I didn't know what it is, I might have clicked on it either way...

Answer (score 25):

[image: An Open Source JavaScript IDE]

Comment: JavaScript IDE and Java like cup of coffee seems a bit tongue in cheek. :)

Answer (score 16):

[image: Help make tool assisted speedruns of videogames on Windows a reality!]

Answer (score 12):

[image: Roadkill .NET Wiki engine]

Comment: This ad isn't formatted as required: it is 220x200 instead of 220x250.

Comment: @Mr. Dissapointment thanks, I've fixed the size + re-uploaded.

Comment: Good stuff; might get pulled through now. :)

Answer (score 11):

[image: The easy-to-use Inversion of Control library for .NET and Silverlight]

Comment: That's pretty terrible jpeg quality.. Can you make a png version?

Comment: @Blorgbeard: Done.

Comment: still terrible ...

Comment: @yes123: Only the quality of the picture is the nurse is low, which I unfortunately can't improve. The image itself is png without loss of quality. Is that the reason for you to downvote?

Comment: I like the software concept and find the image amusing, so I +1'd it a while ago, but the text still looks stretched or contorted in some way. Can you edit this advert in its native 220x250 px format and type the text directly onto that for better readability?  Looking at the text of other adverts and they don't seem to suffer the same degree of artifacts.

Comment: I just tried my suggestion to see if it works, and the text seems more legible, even the small stuff at the bottom   http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/717/samp4lxfx.png/  I used Paint.NET

Comment: @John: Thanks for your reply. I used Paint Shop Pro 7 (I'm a bit old fashion ;-). I think it is the antialiasing of PSP that's the problem. I will retry with Paint.NET. Thanks for the example.

Comment: @John: what do you think about the new image? Better?

Comment: "Addicted" is spelled as "addicted", not as "adicted".

Comment: @Andrey: D'oh! I know that ;-)

Comment: Please vote on the 2012 Advertising: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114442/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2012/124206#124206

Answer (score 10):

[image: Help us integrate PHP and .NET!]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Contribute To the Ronin Synthesizer Platform]

Comment: Thank you very much one and all, we really apreciate the help :)

Answer (score 3):

[image: Zeta Resource Editor - edit .NET string resources in parallel]

Comment: When you're done editing resource files, you can come over and paint my shed. :P (Yes, I'm aware that's the project's logo.)

Comment: Hehe, thanks, I'll try to see whether I get some paint, too :-)