# Glitch with image uploading on Open Source Ads page

Tags: bug, status-completed, open-source-advertising

I created an ad for the [Open Source Advertisement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93312) question and clicked submit only to see:

[image]

That's funny... I *used* the image upload button on the toolbar. Here is a verbatim copy of my post:

```
[![An open-source JavaScript IDE][1]][2]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYjvh.png
  [2]: https://launchpad.net/jsstudio
```

The **real** problem is that on the question itself, it states:

> "Can be hosted anywhere (tinypic, twitpic, your blog); we will mirror the image locally when we serve it."

Comment: Sadly, I was able to duplicate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found and fixed a bug in the validation of the post.  Please try posting this ad again.