# Open Source ads need a more specific focus

Tags: discussion, open-source-advertising

SO's [Open Source advertisement initiative](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93312/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2011) is *great*, but I've been thinking the ads featured should be more concrete in terms of what kind of contributors they are looking for.

Usually, they concentrate on describing what a project *is*, but not what it *needs* from the SO developer community.

Also, the Open Source ads are not tag sensitive (as far as I know). They will be displayed no matter whether the user viewing them matches the required skill set or not!

I personally would feel a lot more called upon by an ad that expresses one or more defined requirements (much like a job ad). If a requirement matches my skill set, I would feel compelled to at least take a peek.

Keywords could be

- Talented C# developers
- Programmers with good writing skills for the end-user documentation
- People to update our API docs
- People with experience in .NET 3.5
- C++ devs with deep knowledge of Linux memory management
- Devs for refactoring the foobar module for the upcoming 2.0 release
- Spanish speakers to translate the end-user documentation

etc.etc.

Hardly any of the ads I've seen transport this kind of specific message.

Just my 2 cents for the upcoming new round of ads!

Comment: That's for the simple fact we're not allowed to put anything in the add topic. And seriously, in that area, how much more can I add than "help us"? I'm supposed to describe the project, describe why people should consider it AND describe what needs to be done...!

Comment: I'm all for the idea, but it's not realistic at this time.

Comment: @Christian it might already be helpful if the projects would link to a page offering "recruitment" details instead of their front page.

Comment: Good point.