# Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 1H 2012

Tags: discussion, community-ads, stack-overflow, open-source-advertising, crowdsourcing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 2H 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132988/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2012)

It's time once again to support your favorite open source project through our Free Vote-Based Advertising for Open Source Projects. We are clearing the leader boards to start the first half of 2012 anew.

Here is your chance to create a [Free Vote-Based Advertisement for an Open Source Project](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/). Create a graphical ad for an open source programming project and post it as an answer to this question (in the right format), and it will feed live remnant ads on Stack Overflow.

### Ad Requirements

It must be an advertisement **soliciting the participation and contribution of programmers writing actual source code**. This is not intended as a general purpose ad for consumer products which just happen to be open source. It's for finding programmers who will help contribute code or other programmery things (documentation, code review, bug fixes, etc.).

Your ad should be an original creation which has not previously appeared on Stack Overflow. Please do not resubmit entries that have appeared as ads on Stack Overflow in previous periods.

In order to work, the answers you post to this question **must** conform to the following rules.

### Answer Template

```
[![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]
    
  [1]: http://image-url
  [2]: http://clickthrough-url
```

Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to add any commentary, keep it in the comments.

### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 pixels by 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

The output, which ultimately will be served in an ad slot on Stack Overflow, can be previewed by clicking through to this URL:

http://rads.stackoverflow.com/ossads/220x250

### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be served up by that URL and shown on Stack Overflow. You can see all the ads that currently make the threshold and meet our criteria on this page:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/114442

**Note:** *As with previous [iterations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93312/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2011-cd) of this program, entries that have appeared as ads in previous periods are not eligible; however, previous entries that did **not** meet the minimum score threshold can be resubmitted.*