# Love your free online advertising program for open-source projects, but

Tags: discussion, reputation, open-source-advertising

I'd sure like to submit an ad to the free open source advertising program, but I am new to Stack Overflow, and I can't upload my image without first having a reputation of 10+. I work for the GNOME Project, and we'd love more input on GNOME3.

Can you help a sister out?

Comment: 6 upvotes in 11 minutes totaling 30 rep: problem solved. :)

Comment: Much appreciated- feelin' the love!

Comment: Voting to close now that the mission is accomplished. (Closing won't lose you the points.)

Comment: Thanks- now you can all vote up my ad at the bottom of this page :)  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114442/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2012

Comment: Have the same issue. Probably, need to ask similar question.