# Advertising Open Source Project

Tags: support, reputation, spam, open-source-advertising

I would like to advertise my [open source project](http://nlist.codeplex.com) on StackExchange. After spending 10 minutes creating a 220x250 image, I was told that new users can't link images. I have been around a while on SO, so I feel this is a little over-protective. I need at least 10 points. Can someone upvote me, please?

Comment: Where are you trying to post the image?

Comment: @Bill: presumably here on Meta, given his image dimensions, his SO rep, and the linked blog post.

Comment: Yeah. It is just a link to imgur.

Comment: There you go.  Maybe some generous soul can cast another vote?

Comment: Or, as Cody Gray says, post your image link, and one of us will convert it to an actual image.

Comment: Thanks everyone! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114442/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the same free image hosting service used by Stack Overflow—[Imgur](http://imgur.com/)—to upload your image, and then include a link to that image in your question.

A user with sufficient reputation will come along and look at your image, deem it acceptable, and add it to your post in-line.

This is much better than begging for upvotes.

Additionally, if you have been around Stack Overflow for a while, you should probably have amassed enough reputation points to be able to post images. If you're talking about posting them on *Meta*, then with 200 or more reputation points on Stack Overflow, you would automatically score 100 points when you created and associated your new account on the Meta site, more than enough to post images.

Comment: I am linked to imgur, but it still doesn't work. I only have about 100 points on SO. This is what I have: [1]: http://i.imgur.com/so9XR.png

Comment: @Travis He meant post an answer on that page with the link instead of the image, and someone with more rep would edit it for you.