# Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 2012

Tags: discussion, community-ads, stack-overflow, open-source-advertising, crowdsourcing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 1H 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162128/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2013)

It's time once again to support your favorite open source project through our Free Vote-Based Advertising for Open Source Projects. We have merged the previous 1H 2012 ads into this post - the 1H ads were not placed in rotation which will be fixed ASAP.

Here is your chance to create a [Free Vote-Based Advertisement for an Open Source Project](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/). Create a graphical ad for an open source programming project and post it as an answer to this question (in the right format), and it will feed live remnant ads on Stack Overflow.

### Ad Requirements

It must be an advertisement **soliciting the participation and contribution of programmers writing actual source code**. This is not intended as a general purpose ad for consumer products which just happen to be open source. It's for finding programmers who will help contribute code or other programmery things (documentation, code review, bug fixes, etc.).

Your ad should be an original creation which has not previously appeared on Stack Overflow. Please do not resubmit entries that have appeared as ads on Stack Overflow in previous periods.

In order to work, the answers you post to this question **must** conform to the following rules.

### Answer Template

```
[![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]
    
  [1]: http://image-url
  [2]: http://clickthrough-url
```

Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to add any commentary, keep it in the comments.

### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 pixels by 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- Must have a 1px border if (part of) the background is white

The output, which ultimately will be served in an ad slot on Stack Overflow, can be previewed by clicking through to this URL:

http://rads.stackoverflow.com/ossads/220x250

### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be served up by that URL and shown on Stack Overflow. You can see all the ads that currently make the threshold and meet our criteria on this page:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/132988

**Note:** *As with previous [iterations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114442/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2012) of this program, if your ad has already appeared in a previous cycle, it is not eligible to be run in this cycle. However, if it did not make it through the previous cycle, it is eligible.*

Comment: If there's no terribly tight deadline, I might be able to make a banner design suggestion for an interesting project in need of one if you love hand-drawn illustrations [as much as I do.](http://pekkagaiser.com/cv/) :)

Comment: Nice work with the answer template pre-loaded!

Comment: **Note:** check out [StackAd](http://stackapps.com/questions/741/stackad-an-easy-way-to-display-open-source-ads-on-your-site-blog) if you are interested in displaying these advertisements on your website / blog.

Comment: How did you get the template to show up in the "Your Answer" box?  Some kind of dev magic?

Comment: @Robert It's the magic "community-ads" tag.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but does [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy) fit here? It's open source but for the life of me couldn't understand if it's "soliciting the participation and contribution of programmers writing actual source code" or not..

Answer (score 77):

[image: Lyfe: yield-based generators in JavaScript]

Comment: I lol'd at the `IE 17`.  It's funny because it's true :-P

Answer (score 56):

[image: Windows console emulator with tabs]

Comment: This is by far my favourite app of 2012. Just brilliant.

Comment: I found out about ConEmu from Hanselman's post. ConEmu is the best terminal application for Windows!

Comment: Better then console2?  Console2 is pretty close to putty (and who doesnt love putty?).  Ill have to check this out!

Answer (score 39):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Answer (score 33):

[image: Contribute to GNOME 3]

Comment: You might want to post this on [Unix and Linux](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/814/community-promotion-ads-2012) and [Ask Ubuntu](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2158/community-promotion-ads-1h-2012) as well

Comment: As a minor comment on the graphics, the small black text on darker blue is a little hard to read at the bottom. Perhaps the white you use for the Linux Journal award could be carried on to the rest of the text.

Comment: @Brad- I agree. Do you have any idea what I would do to submit a revised graphic without going through the whole process again? Thanks!

Comment: @ChristyEller: Edit the answer

Answer (score 24):

[image: WebGit .NET - IIS Hosting for Git Smart-HTTP]

Comment: I don't understand what this project is. Consider adding a readme where you use complete sentences to describe what problem the project solves so that people clicking on the ad will learn what you're asking them to get involved in.

Answer (score 24):

[image: The easy-to-use Inversion of Control library for .NET and Silverlight]

Comment: Can you please update the image? It needs to be 220 x 250px and it needs a 1px border.

Comment: @KorneelBouman: Done.

Comment: @Steven well done good job. I love simple injector. It is really easy, flexible, fast, and friendly

Comment: The text's anti-aliasing and kerning look bad

Comment: Thar woman looks like the 'evil nurse' from an horror movie.  Is that intentional?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Yes it is :-D Or do you prefer the nurse on the [Simple Injector homepage](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com)?

Comment: @Steven  I'd pass on both ..though I might watch the movie.  ;)

Answer (score 21):

[image: UI toolkit running on Linux/Windows/Macosx/Android/IOS, using modern OpenGL! Join!]

Comment: "**The image that you create must be 220 pixels by 250 pixels**". your image will not show up as an ad even if it gets enough votes.

Comment: Image size fixed, i was very tired... sorry :/

Comment: Looks much better now.

Answer (score 21):

[image: WMI Delphi Code Creator (WDCC), allows you to generate Object Pascal, Oxygene, C++ and C# code to access the WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation) Join!]

Comment: I think you mean "needed," to indicate that you're *seeking* developers and testers. With "need it," you're saying this is a tool that developers and testers should use. (And that may be true, but that's not the purpose of these ads.)

Comment: @RobKennedy, thanks for the advice, I chose the wrong word,I will edit the ads.

Answer (score 19):

[image: Show your interest in cloud computing!]

Answer (score 18):

[image: Check out the project!]

Answer (score 18):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: So basically the goal of this application is to expose just about everything inside a PE Executable in an easy-to-read form. For example, if you wanted to know what DLLs you needed to ship with your application, just fire up PE Deconstructor, open the application executable, and click the Imports tab (the latest code in the repo. doesn't have the capability to list imports). You can see an up-to-date screenshot of the application in action [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3SnIj.png).

Comment: Also, for those who are interested in contributing, the application is written in C++ using Qt and is *specifically* designed to run on any platform that Qt will compile on - that means this program behaves the same on Windows, Linux, Mac, even Symbian - just open the application up and take a look at the contents.

Comment: ...and I now have a download for 64-bit Windows users (a 32-bit version and releases for other platforms should come shortly). You can get it here: https://www.box.com/s/06aa8a04a95602ad43e1

Answer (score 15):

[image: NList brings an enormous number of powerful algorithms to the .NET platform.]

Answer (score 12):

[image: Chronicle your own adventure in Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim]

Comment: I know this isn't your typical dev tool (in fact, it's not a dev tool at all). As I read the rules, I think I'm okay to post any open source project that is actively looking for developers. If that's not the case, feel free to let me know.

Comment: Yes it is fine.

Comment: This looks like an ad for the product instead of a call for involvement. You're attracting people who want to *use* the product instead of people who are looking to help *create* it.

Comment: Hm, I think that's fair. I could see a better ad that said something like, "Help build web-based strategy guide software" or something along those lines. The ad does link to the GitHub page as opposed to the website.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Contribute to Linux Mint today!]

Answer (score 10):

[image: would YOU like fries with that? smallFry PHP (m)VC Framework]

Comment: The font is a bit hard to read...

Comment: I kind of like the font. It definitely goes with the picture :P

Comment: @GeorgeEdison ^_^ is there anything I need to add to the ReadMe on the Git?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Answer (score 10):

[image: Tibi's Mathematics Suite]

Comment: Very creative! :D

Answer (score 9):

[image: Cloudify - The Open Source PaaS Stack![][1]]

Answer (score 9):

[image: The SOOMLA Project - Better and Faster In-Game Commerce]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]
<sub>(source: [licel.ru](https://licel.ru/wp-content/uploads/jcardsim.png))</sub>

Answer (score 4):

[image: ASP.NET Calipso: The modern Web Forms!]

Answer (score 3):

[image: netsniff-ng - the packet sniffing beast]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Roadkill .NET Wiki engine]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Help us build a simple, powerful and flexible calendar]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Help Contribute to TouchNet!]

Comment: Can you please update the file? The file format is not  supported and it needs a 1px border. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[image: Programmer Timer]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Histone - open source template engine for Java, JavaScript and PHP]

Comment: There's nothing here, mate.

Comment: Can someone fix the image for me please? I have no enough reputation to upload images, but I know that "A user with sufficient reputation will come along and look at your image, deem it acceptable, and add it to your post in-line."

Comment: Ohh yeah :) It's good now :)