# Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 1H 2013

Tags: discussion, community-ads, stack-overflow, open-source-advertising, crowdsourcing

It's time once again to support your favorite open source project through our Free Vote-Based Advertising for Open Source Projects. We are clearing the leaderboards to start the first half of 2013.

Here is your chance to create a [Free Vote-Based Advertisement for an Open Source Project](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/). Create a graphical ad for an open source programming project and post it as an answer to this question (in the right format), and it will feed live remnant ads on Stack Overflow.

### Ad Requirements

It must be an advertisement **soliciting the participation and contribution of programmers writing actual source code**. This is not intended as a general purpose ad for consumer products which just happen to be open source. It's for finding programmers who will help contribute code or other programmery things (documentation, code review, bug fixes, etc.).

Your ad should be an original creation which has not previously appeared on Stack Overflow. Please do not resubmit entries that have appeared as ads on Stack Overflow in previous periods.

In order to work, the answers you post to this question **must** conform to the following rules.

### Answer Template

```
[![alternative text if image is not displayed][1]][2]
    
  [1]: http://image-url
  [2]: http://clickthrough-url
```

Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to add any commentary, keep it in the comments.

### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 pixels by 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- Must have a 1px border if (part of) the background is white

The output, which ultimately will be served in an ad slot on Stack Overflow, can be previewed by clicking through to this URL:

http://rads.stackoverflow.com/ossads/220x250

### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be served up by that URL and shown on Stack Overflow. You can see all the ads that currently make the threshold and meet our criteria on this page:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/162128

Comment: I am confused... "Your ad should be an original creation which has not previously appeared on Stack Overflow." --> does that mean I can make a new ad for the same project but with a different image? Or does it mean that I cannot even show the project in a Stack Overflow ad ever again?

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Same project, good. Same ad, bad. Users *can* post ads for the same projects, but we want to keep the content fresh; so we ask that users **do not** simply resubmit the same ads over and over.

Comment: @RobertCartaino okey, thanks for the explanation ^_^ Time for me to come up with a new ad image for my project :-D

Comment: some advice for people who are not allowed to post images because their reputation is below 10? (other than raising it :)

Comment: Is a project which is open-development, but not open-source (e.g. not all of the source code is available, but many can work on it together) acceptable?

Comment: @Telthien If the source code is not freely and openly available for redistribution, that would be outside the philosophy of the open source movement for which this promotion is designed. Good luck on your project, but I'm afraid your submission would ***not*** be appropriate for *this* promotion.

Comment: Could someone explain me why my reputation is not transferred from StackOverflow to MetaStackOverflow? I am consequently unable to submit an ad about Orthanc, my open-source project. TIA!

Comment: OK, this answers my comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29404/could-there-be-a-bit-of-reputation-leakage-between-the-sites-please

Comment: I am a bit confused as to where exactly these ads will be/are shown. I do not see any of them appear anywhere now. Could someone please elaborate?

Comment: I am depressed by the quality of the ads here. All developers who try to propagate something should at least leave their github code realm and make a step towards a real world. Please learn how to propagate project from this example: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/q/1968/4630

Comment: Has this program been discontinued? I didn't see a similar post for the second half of 2013. I also found it quite difficult to figure out where to post: would it be possible to put a "this sidebar is obsolete-- see CURRENT LINK for more information" on the older posts?

Comment: Why was an older question marked as a duplicate of a newer question?

Comment: @gparyani These Open Source Ads are a special kind of thread meant for handling our community ads system. They don't follow normal logic, so we basically abuse the close system as a means to point to the latest and currently running post.

Answer (score 41):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: This project is fantastic!

Comment: Using this in a production app, and it is great so far.

Comment: -1 something that even doesn't have a webpage cannot be good. What is promotion good for when you don't have even have a simple page where people can at least see what that project is about? Or do you suppose people will start by studying your code at github?

Comment: @Tomas Obviously you didn't try to go to the documentation page of the Github project where you would find a link to the all available documentation and an introduction video of the usage of the project. Not to mention the logic "something that even doesn't have a webpage cannot be good" is a total absurd.

Comment: Dmitry, it is not obvious where to look for its documentation on the terribly messy GitHub page. Why would I bother? Why would anyone who will click on your ad bother? *You* want to make a propagation, so it is *your* concern to attract people. This is hardly achieved by showing them source code. Don't you understand that?

Comment: I have to agree I could bring that general documentation to the front page. I'll do that. Speaking of "anyone clicking on [the] add". Do you know if these ads display anywhere besides this page?

Comment: Dmitry, bringing documentation is good, but what you need is a very simple presentation that will catch the audience and within few seconds persuade them that they are interested in your project! It must be very brief and very informative in terms of what user can get when he uses your project. I don't know if the ad is used outside SO.

Comment: is there navbar component?
IMHO you should add some components as the YiiBooster did "http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/"

Comment: @yelliver please see [this issue](https://github.com/DmitryEfimenko/TwitterBootstrapMvc/issues/36) to get answer about `NavBar`. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "add some components". Perhaps you could elaborate. Please do so by [opening a new issue on Github](https://github.com/DmitryEfimenko/TwitterBootstrapMvc/issues/new)

Comment: @Dmitry - May I suggest updating the ClickThrough link to point to https://github.com/DmitryEfimenko/TwitterBootstrapMvc/wiki - would do a better job of informing the interested visitor of the project, and then they can choose to navigate to the rest.

Comment: @bPratik - wiki on Github is quite empty. I'll put the contents of the Wiki to the home page (readme file). That should help it a little. One of these days I'll find time to make "Github Pages" for this project.

Answer (score 19):

[image: CodeMirror open-source, online code editor]

Comment: I started using CodeMirror very recently and it's a brilliant project I must say.

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester Yes it is! It's used on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) (my favorite), [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [CodePen](http://codepen.io/), and many other sites.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Fresh IDE, the power of assembly language]

Answer (score 11):

[image: CodeQuery: code searching/ browsing tool]

Comment: A beautiful ad, very nice!

Answer (score 11):

[image: Join Whonix Development!]

Answer (score 9):

[image: 2problems.com web-based regex tester]

Answer (score 9):

[image: Mongoose Embedded Web Server - Join Us!]

Comment: Looks like first real project. But again, why don't you put a link to more reasonable webpage? Or do you present your project just by showing people your code? You should first persuade people to join.

Comment: @Tomas, it's not my project, I've only made some tiny contributions. The page I linked to shows the project's mission and overview; as far as I can tell that's the closest thing the project has to a "sales pitch." I'm not sure there's any reason to persuade people to join; if they're interested in working on an embedded web server they can look at the code, and if it looks like something they'd like to work with they can join. Why try to dress it up?

Comment: I'm pretty sure those are meerkats not mongooses

Answer (score 8):

[image: NPOI is for your .NET + Microsoft Excel needs. Help make it even more AWESOME!]

Comment: "Must have a 1px border if (part of) the background is white"

Answer (score 7):

[image: WMI Delphi Code Creator (WDCC), allows you to generate Object Pascal, Oxygene, C++ and C# code to access the WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation) Join!]

Comment: Having the text overlayed in front of code makes it unreadable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I just modify the ADS.

Answer (score 6):

[image: ReXSL Java Web Framework needs coders passionate about quality]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Zeal - cross-platform documentation browser]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Join the RTEMS Community!]

Comment: I get what you're going for, but the font that's large is hard to read, and the font that's easy to read is too small. These two things combine to make my eyes hurt when I try to read it, which leads to my quickly giving up trying to read it.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Zyan Communication Framework]

Comment: Sorry, I've got not enough reputation points to post images. Could someone please update my post?

Comment: A couple of weeks ago we released a version that supports Android!

Answer (score 5):

[image: Badr: simple, database-driven, multiplatform, .net web framework]

Comment: The project is inspired from django web framework. It tries to make .net web development fun and productive like python/ruby frameworks and easy to learn to pure desktop devs.

Comment: Please use the image upload tool here on the site to prevent image rot: we can't know when external host will do down or decide to delete the image. (Did it for you now)

Comment: Good advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

[image: droidQuery: jQuery for Android]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Java Database Application Library]

Answer (score 3):

[Linear Algebra for Java http://habrastorage.org/storage2/43a/d95/43a/43ad9543a7cc63ecc4c5e9be4961be0c.png](http://la4j.org)

Answer (score 1):

[image: Help develop a intuitive open source tool for metabolomic, proteomic and genomic analysis. It's easier than it sounds!]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Comment: the text is a little squished...

Answer (score -1):

[image: Run your own photo website]

Answer (score -3):

[image: Open source classifieds]

Comment: This is very meta, don't you think?

Comment: The project is open source, but this ad reflects the service, not really the software. You might want an ad that appeals more to programmers that would be interested in contributing, rather than just getting their own site based on the software.

Comment: Changed! Now it reflects the software.

Comment: It’s spelled “classifieds”. I’d also recommend centering the circle of the logo and not the entire image, and using a less boring font.