# Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 2H 2013

Tags: discussion, community-ads, stack-overflow, open-source-advertising, crowdsourcing

It's yet again time once again to again yet support your favorite open source project through our Free Vote-Based Advertising for Open Source Projects. We are clearing the leaderboards to start the second half of 2013.

Here is your chance to create a [Free Vote-Based Advertisement for an Open Source Project](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/). Create a graphical ad for an open source programming project and post it as an answer to this question (in the right format), and it will feed live remnant ads on Stack Overflow.

### Ad Requirements

It must be an advertisement **soliciting the participation and contribution of programmers writing actual source code**. This is not intended as a general purpose ad for consumer products which just happen to be open source. It's for finding programmers who will help contribute code or other programmery things (documentation, code review, bug fixes, etc.).

Your ad should be an original creation which has not previously appeared on Stack Overflow. Please do not resubmit entries that have appeared as ads on Stack Overflow in previous periods.

In order to work, the answers you post to this question **must** conform to the following rules.

### Answer Template

```
[![alternative text if image is not displayed][1]][2]
    
  [1]: http://image-url
  [2]: http://clickthrough-url
```

Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to add any commentary, keep it in the comments.

### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 pixels by 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- Must have a 1px border if (part of) the background is white

The output, which ultimately will be served in an ad slot on Stack Overflow, can be previewed by clicking through to this URL:

http://rads.stackoverflow.com/ossads/220x250

### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be served up by that URL and shown on Stack Overflow. You can see all the ads that currently make the threshold and meet our criteria on this page:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/195823

**Note:** *As with previous [iterations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162128/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2013) of this program, if your ad has already appeared in a previous cycle, it is not eligible to be run in this cycle. However, if it did not make it through the previous cycle, it is eligible.*

Comment: grace note are there any "community promotion ads" for stackoverflow? couldnt find that. yet its on some other stackexchange sites...?

Comment: @vzn Nope, this is what we have instead.

Comment: any discussion of this anywhere? why are community promotion ads restricted to other groups & not open here, any more details on that? members on [cs.se](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) incl moderators have expressed interest in promotion on stackoverflow

Answer (score 24):

[image: Democratize Stenography! Contribute to Plover]

Answer (score 23):

[image: Zyan Communication Framework]

Answer (score 17):

[image: Irony — .NET Language Implementation Kit]

Comment: Is this supposed to be a joke?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 16):

[image: SproutCore: Native-Caliber Web Apps]

Answer (score 15):

[image: alternative text if image is not displayed]

Comment: You've been given [permission to reapply for the next cycle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210389/#comment-674773).

Answer (score 12):

[image: Zyan Drench, a retro-style game for Android with WiFi support]

Answer (score 3):

[image: RaphaGraph graphing library for RaphaelJs]

Answer (score 1):

[image: libde]