# Can I submit several entries for the open source advertising program?

Tags: discussion, open-source-advertising

I've just submitted an ad for the [latest round of the open-source advertising program](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196348/219089). I don't see any rules restricting the number of submissions per user. Is it safe to assume that I can post a few submissions for other projects?

Comment: So long as each one follows the rules, I don't see why not. It's certainly possible for a single user to be involved with multiple open source projects at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Sure.

The system lets you, and the entries are graded by user voting anyway - it can't harm, and it could do some good. Go for it!