# Open-source ads: are they really displayed on Stackoverflow?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, advertising, open-source-advertising

I may be wrong, but it looks to me that community-upvoted advertisements of open-source projects are never displayed on Stackoverflow site. At least, I don't remember seeing any of these ads on the sidebar where [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23899/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects) says they should appear.

Comment: Looking into this... There was a problem and we made some changes to the campaign set up, now we're just waiting to see how these will take. Thanks for letting us know!

Comment: Okidoke - first round of ad server tweaks did... nothing. Made some more changes that should bring them back, but want to see it serve for a day or so before posting official answer.

Answer (score 13):

And we're back... We'll keep an eye on them and may tweak the impression numbers a little, but they're running again.

The ad server has a whole bunch of priorities that you can look at as cascading buckets where impressions are first taken by the highest priority, with the remaining falling through to the priority below etc etc. What happened was that all available impressions where being used up by higher priorities, leaving none available for this campaign. As a fix I've moved it to a higher priority. To catch these things going forward we'll actually start treating ourselves like a client, and run recurring reports on our own ads to see what should be running (and whether it actually is...) rather than trusting they are...

[image]

Comment: You fixed this just for the bounty, didn't you?

Comment: I noticed one for VIM earlier which I never recall seeing before - probably really only actually noticed it because it "looked different" than before and startled me for a moment :)

Answer (score 9):

I did a test. Simple test. I refreshed Stack Overflow homepage about 100 times.

Results:

- 100% of the times, there is pure text Careers advertisement, showing available jobs near me, based on my IP address leading to my ISP location. Fair enough.
- About 30% to 40% of the times, there was additional banner (image) which comes inside `<div>` with class name `everyonelovesstackoverflow adzerk-vote`.
- Out of the times that "everyonelovesstackoverflow" banner appeared, 98% it was Careers and 2% (2 out of the 100) it was a nice and graphic banner to the [gaming site](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/).

Based on this, I would say there is a bug here preventing open source ads (there are four eligible now) plus the "third party" ads that I used to see once, from appearing. Surprised those who pay for those ads to show didn't notice that first. (unless of course there are no more paying advertisers, which I doubt)

Tried both logged in and as anonymous visitor.

Comment: +1 I just posted the same question, but expanded with additional observations: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202388 and it was closed as a duplicate. This question here, actually has no answer, but just a opinions. So, I have a hypothesis that the missing banners are known and probably intentional behavior.

Comment: @johnfound a dev marked this as bug so I don't think it's intentional, more likely mistake causing them to be missing.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they are displayed, see [Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 2H 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195823/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2013)

However, there is a score threshold of 6 votes before an ad posted there is considered for rotation at all, and there is currently only [one ad eligible](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/195823). It received 25 clicks at the time of posting, according to that page, so presumably *someone* sees these.

With only one OSS advertisement in rotation, perhaps you missed it?

Comment: I'm noting the "Clicks per day: 0.86 (24 total) " which suggests someone must be seeing it and its been available for 28 days

Comment: [This page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/195823) displays ads that currently make the threshold, and clicking on them increments the counter. That doesn't mean that ads are really served at stackoverflow pages, however.
The ad you mentioned had about 20 clicks by the end of the day it passed the threshold (about two weeks ago),
and it got 4 or 5 clicks since then. To me, it looks more like clicks received at [this page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/195823) from the readers of [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195823).

Comment: The question page itself doesn't track clicks. You'd have to go through to the list of eligible ads first, then click, to increment that counter. I really do not think that those 25 clicks were all *just* via that page.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - see my answer below for possible clicks source.

Comment: @johnfound: and how did that blog use the banners?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Well, I don't know. I simply don't remember. But can you provide some screenshot of SO page, displaying these banners?

Comment: @johnfound: I have no screenshot, no. And since Oded marked this as a bug, I am beginning to suspect that I won't be able to get one, either.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly an answer, but some more observations. I participated in the previous half year program and once working on the SEO of my site I incidentally found an open source blog that demonstrated the banners from the Stack Overflow program.

And if there is one, then probably there are more such sites.

So, the banner clicks showed in the statistics, possibly are generated on an 3rd party sites, willing to advertise open source projects.