# A question about the "open source advertising" on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, open-source-advertising

As I can see in *[Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 2H 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195823)*, the program is still active. But according to the Stack Exchange blog post *[Free Vote-Based Advertising for Open Source Projects](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/)*, the voted banners have to be demonstrated on the Stack Overflow main site. But I never saw any of these banners there.

I know that the statistics show some clicks on the banners, but I am sure I saw these banners on a open source related blog (sorry I can't find the link just now) and this means that these clicks can be collected from some 3rd party sites that like to advertise open source projects.

What is the reason? Is it a bug? Did someone ever saw at least one of the mentioned banners on the Stack Overflow front page?