# Are historically-locked questions supposed to be hidden on meta sites now?

Tags: support, meta, per-site-meta, historical-lock

On main Q&A sites, it's always been the case that questions with historical locks are "hidden" or "unlisted" from most users: they don't turn up in any question lists, and only show if someone follows direct links to them.

[Since May 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/126631/6), though, such questions weren't supposed to be hidden in this manner on meta sites.

But this doesn't seem to be the case anymore. [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162128/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2013) on this site has a historical lock, and is tagged [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads). However, if you follow the tag link above, you won't see that question listed in the list of questions with that tag.

At first, I thought that this was a Meta.SE specific bug, as it was being treated as a main site for these purposes. However, I have two reasons to doubt that: first, this site is correctly classed as a meta site for many other purposes (e.g. allowing unanswered duplicate targets, disabling the `RemoveAbandonedQuestions` Roomba criterion, etc.), and second, I found [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273468/377214) which talks about a historically-locked question on a per-site meta that was hidden in the same manner. That post was made in January 2016, so it seems to have been broken for a long while.

Why are historically-locked questions hidden on meta sites now? Is this a (long-standing) bug, or was there a feature change at some point? (Or was the May 2012 edit incorrect?)

Comment: This seems to be only related to the [community-ads] tag. That question appears (at least for me) in the list of questions with either [[tag:crowdsourcing]] or [[tag:open-source-advertising]] (the only other two that I checked).

Comment: Looks like it also appears under [community-ads] but only when the list is [sorted by votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-ads?tab=Votes).

Comment: @41686d6564 for me it only appears when **not** sorted by votes.

Comment: There are only five posts tagged [community-ads], but each question is closed as a duplicate, until you find the historical-locked post which is [Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 1H 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162128), which itself was closed a dupe of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195823/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2013 with an identical title, closed, not locked, as a dupe of [Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 1H 2014](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251196) on SO, which again was closed as a dupe of.... and then I got bored.