# Don't show the posts in the sandbox, between the low quality posts

Tags: feature-request, sandbox

The low quality posts contains also the posts written in the [sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox), which are clearly low quality, as their only purpose is to test how some Markdown markup is rendered.

It would be helpful if the posts contained in the sandbox would not appear in the review page.

Other posts that should not probably appear are the ones contained in questions such as, [Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 1H 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31913/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2010/50682#50682), where the answers just contain a link with an image.

Comment: There's less than 100 posts there...Is it really that onerous that a special case needs to be coded for them?

Comment: The code would just need to check the ID of the parent post, or the post ID, in the case of the sandbox question. 101 posts is the actual value, which means at least two pages of the pager, but that is not the maximum number of posts there could be in the sandbox.

Comment: @KevinVermeer Actually, there are more posts that could be filtered out, such as the "Open Source Advertising" series.

Comment: I didn't realize anyone actually *used* the "low quality" review page on **MSO**. Some of the recent flags make a lot more sense now...