# Can we have StackApps advertisements running on SO?

Tags: feature-request, stackapps, advertising

We currently have a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53346/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2010) where you can post [ads for open-source software](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23899/proposal-free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects) and they get shown on StackOverflow.

Can we have something similar for StackOverflow API applications?

Benefits:

- Raises awareness for API
- Helps get people to test the applications
- Brings much needed exposure for the apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feel free to post your app as an open source project in the open source adds question.  If it garnishes enough upvotes it will join the rotation.

You [have already done this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53346/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2010/53466#53466) for your so++ library.

Comment: What about StackMobile? It's not open-source. Same with StackImage, StackMail, etc.

Comment: Well, I guess if you are asking for free advertising for closed-source projects, then you may have a difficult time getting that.  They already advertise the api with the contest ad.  Maybe you should inquire how much they would charge to run a stackmobile ad... (@george)

Comment: That's ridiculous. I'm not making money off StackMobile. In fact it's *using up* bandwidth. And it's basically helping StackOverfow by making the site more accessible **and** promoting the API.

Comment: @George, it is kind of ridiculous.  But, my guess is, that's the only way you would get any advertising from SO.