# Make Open Source Advertising statistics available even after the ads stop running

Tags: feature-request, statistics, open-source-advertising

I'm building a advertisement for the next round of [Open Source Advertising](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23899/proposal-free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects) that will (presumably) start soon. You can see the stats for the current round of ads [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/ossads/all), and that is helpful for me in determining what might type of ad might be more successful for Stack Overflow.

Unfortunately, the [first round](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31913/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2010) also contained many great ads, and I would like to see the statistics for some them. Is it possible to publish the stats for the first round of ads too?