# Start a new Stack Overflow tag for my project

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation

I have seen Stack Overflow used to great success as a substitute for mailing lists and support forums for various projects.

How can I get my project (Spikepy) a tag?  I read that you need 1500 Rep.  If that is the case, can I find someone nice enough to start a [spikepy](/questions/tagged/spikepy) tag?

Comment: this is advertising and even if it wasnt, this type of question should be on meta.
you may be interested in this though: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23899/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects

Comment: I think the downvoter is a little harsh, however this question would be better on Meta.

Comment: You mean the documentation and help is _lacking_?

Comment: I didn't mean to faux pas or to use SO overtly for advertising, since my project is very niche, I don't think general SO advertising would help.  I just wanted to utilize SO for what I thought it was, and I thought you had to have rep to add tags.  Also, I didn't know there was a meta-SO, this definately belongs here and not on SO proper.

Comment: Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/is-it-okay-to-use-stack-overflow-as-the-support-forum-for-a-product-or-project

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tags are not created beforehand. They are created **on demand**. If someone has a question and it involves your project, he might tag it as such.

SO is surely not a replacement for a support forum for a *specific project*.

Comment: How to avoid to close that tag's question as "too localized"?

Answer (score 0):

Tags are organic.

If your project becomes popular enough it will organically get a tag, an example would be something like ruby-on-rails or jQuery